# How can all those tiny polygons generated by RegionPlot be joined into a single FilledCurve?

Tags: graphics

`RegionPlot` will usually generate a large number of tiny polygons for filling the region:

```
RegionPlot[-1 < x < 1 && -1 < y < 1 && x^2 + y^2 > 4/5, {x, -1.2, 
  1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When exported to PDF, these are often not very fast to render.

It is clear that theoretically these polygons could be joined into a single `FilledCurve`, defined by the outlines only. This should be much faster to render.

How can we do this in a robust way?

---

Note: the reason we need a `FilledCurve` and that a plain `Polygon` will not work is that a `FilledCurve` can have a hole in it (it may be [multiply connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplyConnected.html)), like in the image above.  Alternatively I will accept a solution which uses more than one `Polygon`, but still reduces the number of `Polygons`s as much as possible (in the example above two polygons will suffice).

---

Here's a complex `RegionPlot` to test on:

```
a = 36;
g = RegionPlot[
  Mod[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 7/2 ArcTan[x, y] + Sin[x] + 
     Cos[y], π] < π/2, {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

The equation is from [here](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/gallery/margarita.html).

Comment: Wow, that last code gives beautiful graphics. Was it made up or does it have a story?

Comment: @Vitaliy It's a GrafEq demo.  See the very last link in my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could start by extracting the `Line` primitives from the normalized `GraphicsComplex`:

```
a=36;

g=RegionPlot[Mod[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]-7/2 ArcTan[x,y]+Sin[x]+Cos[y],Pi]<Pi/2,
 {x,-a,a},{y,-a,a},PlotPoints->100];

lines=Cases[Normal[g], _Line, Infinity];
```

The lines can then be directly included in a `FilledCurve`:

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm@Directive[Black, Thickness[Medium]], 
  FaceForm@Directive[Opacity[1/2], Orange], 
  FilledCurve[List /@ lines]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This renders noticeably faster even within Mathematica (for example during resizing).

The structure of the `FilledCurve` must follow the `FilledCurve[{{Line[...]}, {Line[...]}, ...}]` pattern in order for the holes to show correctly.  Each line must be included in a separate sublist.

---

If each `Line` is included in a separate `FilledCurve`, then the holes will be missing:

```
Graphics[FilledCurve/@lines]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we use the `FilledCurve[{Line[...], Line[...], ...}]` structure, the lines will be effectively concatenated into one continuous line, causing artefacts:

```
Graphics[FilledCurve[lines]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I used this directly on @Szabolcs plot, and all I got was a blank image.

Comment: @rcollyer - Was that with the Mesh->All setting? Because there are no Line primitives with that setting.

Comment: Removed `Mesh -> All` got a black rectangle.

Comment: @rcollyer - In the simpler case this seems to work (but it breaks the more complicated case): `Graphics[FilledCurve[lines]]`

Comment: Odd. I'm looking at the forms of both, and I don't understand why `Map` would work at all. I'll look at it again after I get some sleep.

Comment: That is exactly my problem: I can either fill up the holes, which is incorrect (the `Map` method), or get many artefacts for reasons I don't understand (the second method).  Do you understand why the second method doesn't work generally?  We need a simpler test case.

Comment: I got it, the solution is `FilledCurve[List /@ lines]`. Since you're probably sleeping now, I'll edit your answer. Please review the edit, proofread it, and I'll accept afterwards!

Comment: @Szabolcs - Yes, I think you got it. I could not get this correct myself yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: hi guys, is it possible to generalize this code as to automatically maintain the color of the filled areas? i often have a `ListContourPlot` with 3-4 different colors