# Exporting a dashed plot with a color gradient to a vector graphics format ruins the dashing

Tags: plotting, export, bugs, color

When exporting a dashed plot with a color gradient to a vector graphics format such as EPS or PDF, the dashing is partly ruined.  For example, this command:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thick], ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

Creates the following plot:

[image: A dashed plot with a color gradient exported to png]

However, when exporting the plot to EPS or PDF, I get this plot (notice the ruined dashing, especially near the vertex of the parabola):

[image: A dashed plot with a color gradient exported to eps]

- **<del>Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?</del>**
- **<del>If</del> it is a bug, is there a workaround?**

I am using Mathematica version 8.0.4.0 (*edit:* on Win7 64bit)

**Edit:** I got an email from wolfram support, which I understand confirms this is a bug. Until they fix it, any workarounds which properly export the plot as *vector graphics* are welcome.

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: Reproduced on 8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 5, 2011)

Comment: Reproduced on WinXP/8.0.4 as well.

Comment: Also reproducible under Win7 64bit/8.0.4, both with `Export[...]` and withe the `Save Graphics as...` menu option.

Comment: The answer given by @Peter below is based on a post by me on MathGroup. I also gave it as an answer [on this web site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1551/245), see the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `VertexColors` that get introduced when a `ColorFunction` is specified are not rendered smoothly in the exported `PDF` - *no matter what* other options (such as `Dashed`) you specify. So we really have *two* problems here. Bad color gradients along the line, and incorrect computation of the dash spacing.

If you don't care too much about the bad color gradients and just want a plot with an acceptable dashing, you could do something like this:

```
Show[#,
   Graphics[{Thickness[.01], White, Dashing[{.02, .04}], 
     Cases[Normal@#[[1]], Line[_], Infinity]}]] &@
 Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.008], 
  ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

Here I have taken your original `Plot` and initially removed the dashing. Before showing this plot, I extract from it the `Line` that was produced, re-draw it a second time *with* dashing and slightly larger thickness at the *background color* (`White`).

Finally, I place the dashed white line on top of the continuous colored line to get the appearance of a *dashed colored* line. For this to look correct in the *exported* `PDF`, you have to play with the `Dashing` and `Thickness` manually.

The dashing in the export will look different from the notebook. In particular, the second number in `Dashing[{0.02,0.04}]` must always be bigger than the first, or else you don't see anything!

Here is what the exported `PDF` looks like with the above command:

[image: PDF]

If you *do care* about the bad color gradients in addition to the dashing, then I would suggest going with bitmap export right now because it would take a bitmap-based hack to get smooth color gradients in the `PDF` anyway.

Comment: Nice! I guess that's the best that can be done until Wolfram fixes the bug...

Answer (score 6):

The wrong dashing goes away if you use the following rule, which I found in [this MathGroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/GyzqqkudKp8/1lAqLMYOf7kJ) post by Jens, as a hint to downsize the pdf-size and to eliminate the spurious edges coming up with saved `DensityPlots`, `ParametricPlot3D` etc. The setting is:

```
rasterProlog={{EdgeForm[], Texture[{{0, 0, 0, 0}}], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]}}
```

All one has to do to write: `pl = Plot[..., Prolog -> rasterProlog]` and then `Export`.

`Export[filename, Show[pl, Prolog->rasterProlog]` works as well, if you don't want to include the `Prolog` in `Plot`, `DensityPlot`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, your solution rasterizes the plot, which defeats the purpose of using a vector graphics format such as EPS or PDF. I want a vector graphics format since it allows enlarging the plot as much as I want without loss of quality, and it allows editing individual elements in the saved plot as discrete objects. If I wanted a rasterized plot I could have just used a raster format such as PNG, since when exporting to a raster format the dashing isn't ruined in the first place.