# How can I prevent ColorFunction from disabling antialiasing in graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, color

When I use `ColorFunction`, the appearance of my plots is ruined, changing from this

[image: Nice antialiased plot]

which has the normal smooth lines and antialiased fonts, to this

[image: Ugly plot]

in which the line for the plot has become jagged and thin, and the fonts have lost their clear appearance, and the points have become jagged and have even shifted position a bit. The latter figure is useless to me.

How do I prevent this behavior? Is there a setting somewhere that I missed?

Setting the "Antialiasing Quality" to "Highest Quality" in Preferences, partly remedies the problem with the line, but points, fonts, and axes still shift, as if the scale of the figure has been changed:

[image]

---

```
Manipulate[Show[
  {If[showcf, 
    ParametricPlot[{u, Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     ColorFunction -> (White &), PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.02]}], {}],
   ParametricPlot[{u, Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}],
   Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{Pi, 0.5}], White, 
     PointSize[Medium], Point[{Pi, 0.5}]}]}],
 {{showcf, False, "Show ColorFunction"}, {True, False}}]
```

Comment: I don't see any such thing.

Comment: @rm-rf: Interesting. Any chance there are system settings (OS X) that could be causing this to which `Mathematica` would be sensitive, or perhaps some global `Mathematica` settings?

Comment: @rm-rf: I've tried the only system setting I know of that could possibly affect this, font smoothing, to no effect.

Comment: I get the same thing (on Windows 7, Mathematica 8.04). The text in e.g. `Plot[x,{x,0,1}]` is smoothed with ClearType (subpixel rendering), whereas the text in `Plot[x,{x,0,1},ColorFunction->(Blue&)]` is not. If I turn off ClearType the text in both plots is the same.

Comment: @SimonWoods: What happens to the point? Does it get scrambled? And the axes: do the shift a bit , and get blurry?

Comment: The white point moves relative to the black point, like in your picture, and the axes move a tiny bit but don't go blurry. The tick marks get smaller too.

Comment: @SimonWoods: Sounds like a bug.

Comment: This seems to be related to the bug in [Exporting a dashed plot with a color gradient to a vector graphics format ruins the dashing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5895/245). Again it's the `VertexColors` that cause the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit for version 10**

> This bug seems to have been fixed in *Mathematica* version 10 on OS X.
> The solution below is neither needed nor functional in version 10. It
> was intended for version 8.

The problem is caused by the appearance of `VertexColors` in the plot. Increasing the antialiasing quality doesn't really fix this, as you can see by exporting one of those plots to `PDF`. The color gradients are all wrong.

In principle, one can work around this by getting rid of the `VertexColors` and replacing them by rasterized images. Here is an attempt to do this for 2d line plots. It works in the context of this question, but should also work for other plots (maybe with additional adjustments):

```
Options[removeVertexCol] = {ImageResolution -> 300};

removeVertexCol[pp_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[
  {pa, img, rangeCoords, plotRangeRule, x, noVertexPl},
  pa = Show[
    pp,
    Axes -> None, Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    ImagePadding -> None
    ];
  img = Rasterize[
    pa,
    "Image", ImageResolution -> OptionValue[ImageResolution]
    ];
  plotRangeRule = AbsoluteOptions[pp, PlotRange];
  rangeCoords = Transpose[PlotRange /. plotRangeRule];
  noVertexPl = 
   Normal[(pp /. HoldPattern[VertexColors -> x__] :> Sequence[])];
  Show[
   Graphics[
    First[
      noVertexPl
      ] /. _?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor, GrayLevel}, 
          Head[#]] &) -> RGBColor[1, 1, 1, 0],
    Rest[List @@ noVertexPl]
    ],
   Prolog -> Inset[
     Show[img, AspectRatio -> Full], rangeCoords[[1]], {0, 0}, 
     Subtract @@ rangeCoords
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

The function takes an option `ImageResolution`.

The idea is to make a rasterized version of the plot `pp` without axes and frames, and then underlay it with the original plot after removing all `VertexColors` from the latter. To make sure the two graphics are aligned, I remove any `PlotRangePadding` before rasterizing the plot. This means that you should avoid using `PlotRangePadding` in the original plot, and instead create any desired spacing by using an explicit `PlotRange`.

Below is how I would apply the above function to your example:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   If[showcf,
    removeVertexCol@
     ParametricPlot[{u, Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
      PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.02]}, 
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.1, 1.1}}], {}
    ],
   ParametricPlot[{u, Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.1, 1.1}}], 
   Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{Pi, 0.5}], White, 
     PointSize[Medium], Point[{Pi, 0.5}]}
    ]}
  ], {{showcf, False, "Show ColorFunction"}, {True, False}}]
```

The antialiasing is now preserved.

**Edit**

You may also look into replacing `Show` by `Overlay` in your example. But I don't have time to work out the details of the alignment - may get back later.

**Edit 2**

I made just a few modifications to your original code to get it to work with `Overlay`:

```
Manipulate[Overlay[
  {If[showcf, removeVertexCol@ParametricPlot[{u, Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
      ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.02]}, 
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
      AxesStyle -> Opacity[0]],
    ""
    ], ParametricPlot[{u, Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.1, 1.1}},
    Epilog -> {
      Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{Pi, 0.5}], White, 
      PointSize[Medium], Point[{Pi, 0.5}]
      }
    ]
   }
  ], {{showcf, False, "Show ColorFunction"}, {True, False}}]
```

[image: Manipulate with Overlay]

The circle/dot is now an `Epilog` in the second plot so that it is placed relative to the coordinates of that plot.

Comment: That works wonderfully — *but* (a) it not only seems like an extraordinary amount of fiddling to go through in order to get what should clearly be the default behavior, (b) it's also a bit slow. As for (a), I'd call this a serious bug. As far as (b) is concerned, is there a way to speed things up? I use this inside of a manipulate that needs to be very responsive.

Comment: See my edit - `Overlay` doesn't look jagged on the screen...

Comment: Overlay is very promising, though I (in addition to having to make the axes to the first plot invisible, which is no problem) I get the point in what seems to be a separate region below the plots.

Comment: I've added a quick fix using `Overlay` and placing the dot inside one of the plots. Seems to work fine in the `Manipulate`. Anyway, it's certainly a bug.

Comment: @Jens - I'm trying to use this function for [this quasi-duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134701/fixing-labels-in-plots-with-colorfunction), but it looks bad because there's still a black line under the line with `VertexColors`, due to the fact that there is no color to replace.  I get a decent result if I change that replacement rule to `a_Line :> {Opacity[0], a}`.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the Antialiasing Quality to 'Highest Quality' in the Preferences dialog.
This makes a significant difference on my computer (Windows):

[image]

Comment: That makes a big difference, but the fonts and axes still change, as do points (added to question), as if the scale of the whole figure has been changed.