# ListLinePlot with colors from data

Tags: graphics, color, plotting

I am trying to color a simple 2D plot (using `ListLinePlot`) based on data in the form of 3-vectors.

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]]]
```

I would like to use one of the `ColorData` color schemes (like "Temperature") for the line color, depending on this third value in my table 3-vectors.  That is,`Data[[All, 3]]` will be the source of the color-coding values.

Comment: Perhaps supply some sample data?

Comment: Think of using ListContourPlot. it may help you viewing the data more efficiently

Comment: Related question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21717/3066)

Answer (score 5):

I *think* something like this is what you're after (I created some data for this example):

```
data = Range@20;
tbl = Transpose[{data, data^3, data/25}];

ListLinePlot[tbl[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Darker[ColorData["Temperature"][tbl[[Round[x], 3]]], .2]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Setting the `ColorFunctionScaling` to `False` gets you the `X` value which is then used to index back into your data to get the desired index of the color scheme. Note that if your actual `X` values are not integers, you'll need to use other means (lookup, or an incrementing counter) to index into the desired color. Here's an example of that:

```
colors = tbl[[All, 3]]l
cnt = 1;

ListLinePlot[tbl[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Darker[ColorData["Temperature"][colors[[cnt++]]], .2]]]
```

Comment: This is how it *should* work (+1), but there is one pesky issue: as soon as `VertexColors` appear in the plot (which this approach uses behind the scenes), the output is **no longer anti-aliased**. This can make the lines appear ugly and jagged if you look closely. This has been addressed in [How can I prevent ColorFunction from disabling antialiasing in graphics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14071/245) where I wrap the plot output in a function `removeVertexCol` to get rid of the `VertexColors`.

Comment: @Jens:Ah! Thanks for the addition - bookmarked your linked post!

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Table[{Cos[k 2 Pi/7.], Sin[k 2 Pi/7.], k/21.}, {k, 0, 21, 3}];

colors = VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Last /@ data)

plot = ListLinePlot[Most /@ data, AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue@y]];

plot[[1, 2, 3]] = colors;

plot
```

[image]

Comment: For me this doesn't work (version 8). It's a little more robust if you use a replacement rule to look directly for `VertexColors`: for example, `plot /. HoldPattern[VertexColors -> Automatic] :> colors` works for me. But you do lose the anti-aliasing as I mentioned below @Kuba's answer, too.

Comment: @Jens - In 9.01 it works, but my example is, of course, more than ugly. Meanwhile I learnt by self-teaching, how to plug in complicated functions via `ColorFunction` into a `ParametricPlot` to color it , for example, according to its `curvature`. Only being 50% satisfied with my results so far, I'll ask a similar question to SE in a couple of days. Hopefully, you will read it.