# Fixing labels in plots with ColorFunction

Tags: formatting

Whenever I use `ColorFunction`, the labels look odd. The text is thin.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this and make the labels look normal (like plot below)? Or is this just a bug that I cannot work around?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post and include the *Mathematica* code you used to generate these plots. In addition, I feel like specifying the version that you have will be important in this case.

Comment: This is related to the `VertexColors`, but clearly **isn't** fixed in version 10 for OSX, because I get the same result in all versions.  You can see it via `opts = {ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 22}};
pts = {#, Sin@#} & /@ Range[0, 4 \[Pi], .1];
colors = Hue@Sin@#2 & @@@ pts;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  Line[pts, VertexColors -> If[showVertexColors, colors, None]], 
  Sequence@opts], {{showVertexColors, False, 
   "Show VertexColors"}, {True, False}}]`

Comment: Also, it happens **even if** you wrap the `Graphics` command with `Style[<graphics>, Antialiasing -> False ]`