# ColorFunction makes choppy line in Plot

Tags: plotting, piecewise, plot-themes

I'm trying to apply a `ColorFunction[]` to a piecewise plot. For some reason, applying the `ColorFunction[]` to a plot results in aliasing artifacts (as seen in the image). Is there anyway to get rid of this?
(Mathematica 11.0)

```
cf[x_] := If[x <= 0, Black, Blue];
Rasterize[
 Column[{
   Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
    ColorFunction -> cf, ImageSize -> Large],
   Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> Large]
   }], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Color Function Aliasing]

Comment: maybe you can use `MeshShading` instead of `ColorFunction`: `Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Black, Blue}]` to get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r1jaS.png)

Comment: closely related Q/A: [How can I prevent ColorFunction from disabling antialiasing in graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14059/125)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MeshShading` instead of `ColorFunction`

```
Rasterize[
 Column[{Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
    Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Black, Blue}, ImageSize -> Large], 
   Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> Large]}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]