# Can I dash only the invisible edges of dodecahedron?

Tags: graphics3d, geographics

I'm new to Mathematica and trying to draw a dodecahedron. Here's my code and output:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.15], Purple, 
   Dodecahedron[0.72`]}, {Background -> None, ViewPoint -> Above, 
   Boxed -> False}]]
```

[image]

Is there a way I can dash only the invisible edges of this solid? I noticed some examples have shown that we could make all edges have the same property, but I wonder if I could only dash part of them.

**Update**: I used the function `Graphics3DSketch` to do that:

```
Graphics3DSketch[
 Graphics3D[{PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Polygons"], 
   PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Lines"]}, Boxed -> False]
 , ViewPoint -> Above
 ]
```

Looks like it works, but the graph is out of the range. How can I adjust that? Also, is there a way I can rotate the view clockwise by a certain amount?
[image]
Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45410/sketch-type-graphics-with-transparency-and-dashed-hidden-lines/45435#45435.  Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21079

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks for the comment, I just updated my question:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be no automatic way to get the image range set right, so I used `ViewAngle`.  You can rotate the orientation of the view using `ViewVertical`.

```
foo = ResourceFunction["Graphics3DSketch"];
    
amount = 37.5 Degree;
ggg = foo[
   Graphics3D[{PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Polygons"], 
     PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Lines"]}, Boxed -> False], 
   ViewPoint -> Above, ViewAngle -> 40 Degree, 
   ViewVertical -> {Cos[amount], Sin[amount], 0}];
ggg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help:)