# Can I draw a sphere using Graphics3DSketch?

Tags: graphics3d, resourcefunction

I've seen a very nice example to draw a sphere with dashed longitude/latitude in the invisible part: [Dashed mesh behind 3D object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/dashed-mesh-behind-3d-object/21079#21079). I wonder is it possible for me to only include the equator and two perpendicular longitudes of the sphere? Can I do that using the resource function `Graphics3DSketch`? To draw a polyhedron, I used `PolyhedronData`, but I'm not sure how can I do that for a sphere and how to define the longitude/latitude I want to draw. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
aa = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}]; 
bb = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.015]];
cc =  ParametricPlot3D[{0, Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]]}, 
      {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.015]];
dd =  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Phi]], 0, Sin[\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.015]];
Show[aa, bb, cc, dd]
```

[image]

```
ResourceFunction["Graphics3DSketch"][{aa, bb, cc, dd}]
```

[image]