# How to draw the dashed line automatic behind of a pyramid?

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to draw this pyramid like this
[image]

I tried

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = 
  Pyramid[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], 
  FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[0.2]}], \[ScriptCapitalR]}
 , Boxed -> False]
```

I got
[image]

How to draw the dashed line automatic behind of a pyramid? like this
[Dashed mesh behind 3D object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/dashed-mesh-behind-3d-object/238191#238191)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a ***fixed viewpoint***, you can use [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html) with the option [`MeshCellStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellStyle.html) to style individual line primitives:

```
pyramid = Pyramid[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}];

Show[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[pyramid , 
  MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity,
  PlotTheme -> "Lines", 
  MeshCellStyle -> {{1, 4|5|8} -> Directive[Black, Dashing[Large]], {1, _} -> Black},
  MeshCellLabel -> MapThread[{0, #} -> Placed[Style[#2, 16, Bold], #3] &, 
    {Range @ 5, {"C", "D", " B", "A ", "S"}, {Below, Below, After, Before, Above}}],
  ViewPoint -> {.1, -3, 1}]] /. {_Line} :> {}
```

[image]

**Update:**

We can use a slight modification of the function `DashedGraphics3D`  from [this answer by Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45435/125) to get a 2D image of `Graphics3D` object with lines behind the front surface rendered as dashed lines. The only changes I made in the function are to add `Pyramid` in the list of 3D primitives,

```
face3DPrimitives = {Pyramid, Cuboid, Cone, Cylinder, Sphere, Tube, 
  BSplineSurface}
```

and replace `Dashed` with `Dashing[Large]`:

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom[7]

Grid[Transpose @ Table[
  {Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Directive[Opacity@.5, LightBlue]], 
      EdgeForm[Thick], pyramid}, 
     Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> v, 
     ImageSize -> 400, SphericalRegion -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> PromptForm[Style["view point", 16], Style[v, 16]]], 
   Show[DashedGraphics3D[Graphics3D[pyramid, Boxed -> False],  
      ViewPoint -> v, ImagePadding -> 120], ImageSize -> 300]},
   {v, Round[ RandomReal[{-2, 3}, {4, 3}], .01]}], 
  Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: But if  `ViewPoint -> {8, 3, 7}` ?

Comment: @cvgmt, you need to replace `4|5|8` _manually_ with appropriate list of indices for each spec for `ViewPoint`. For `ViewPoint -> {8, 3, 7}` the pattern `1|3|5` works. (You can use the option `MeshCellLabel ->  Join[Thread[ Thread[{0,   Range[5]}] -> (Style[#, Bold, 16] & /@ {"C", "D", "B", "A",  "S"})], {{1, All} -> "Index"}]` to see the indices of line primitives.)

Comment: When I rotate the output of Mathematica, I get incorrect about dashed lines. How to draw the dashed line automatic like when I rotate the sphere at the link in my question?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter, this method works for a _fixed view point_. (I will post an answer with a method that works for dynamically changing viewpoint.)

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter, please see the update.

Comment: @kglr Thank you very much. I do not see [this answer by Silvia]

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter, sorry forgot to paste the link. Added now.

Comment: @kglr I can not get the resullt. I copied all your code 
`SeedRandom[7]
Grid[Transpose @ Table[
  {Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Directive[Opacity@.5, LightBlue]], 
      EdgeForm[Thick], pyramid}, 
     Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> v, 
     ImageSize -> 400, SphericalRegion -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> PromptForm[Style["view point", 16], Style[v, 16]]], 
   Show[DashedGraphics3D[Graphics3D[pyramid, Boxed -> False],  
      ViewPoint -> v, ImagePadding -> 120], ImageSize -> 300]},
   {v, Round[ RandomReal[{-2, 3}, {4, 3}], .01]}], 
  Spacings -> {1, 1}]
`

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter, did you make the change in silvia's `DashedGraphics3D` code ( that is,is replace `face3DPrimitives = { Cuboid, Cone, Cylinder, Sphere, Tube, BSplineSurface}` with `face3DPrimitives = {Pyramid, Cuboid, Cone, Cylinder, Sphere, Tube, BSplineSurface}`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130533/discussion-between-john-paul-peter-and-kglr).

Answer (score 7):

To make the hidden line dashed is pretty complicated. However, if you can live with hidden lines drawn only faintly, you may use the option "Opacity" like:

```
base = {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}};
top = {{0, 0, 2}};
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.01]], Opacity[0.8], 
  Triangle[Join[top, #]] & /@ Partition[base, 2, 1, {1, 1}]}]
```

[image]