# How can I draw dashed line behind of a cone?

Tags: graphics3d

I use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools) to draw this cones
[image]

shaded cone

[image]

I see difficult when I use *Mathematica*

```
Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 2], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

How can I draw  dashed line behind of a cone?

***UPDATE***

I tried

```
    basegraph = 
     Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1.2], Boxed -> False]
ResourceFunction["Graphics3DSketch"][basegraph]
```

I get

[image]

How can I get shaded cone like my picture?

Comment: Have you seen [256898](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256898/how-to-draw-the-dashed-line-automatic-behind-of-a-pyramid) ?

Comment: Also see [Graphics3DSketch](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Graphics3DSketch/) from the Wolfram Function Repository mentioned in this [popular](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45410/sketch-type-graphics-with-transparency-and-dashed-hidden-lines) post.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.

Comment: You can also use the trick I used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289031/36508)

Comment: `DynamicModule[{point = 4 {1, -1, 1}, vertical = {0, 0, 1}, 
  angle = 10 Degree},
 Overlay[
  Graphics3D[#, Boxed -> False, 
     Lighting -> DirectionalLight[White, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}], 
     ViewPoint -> Dynamic@point, ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vertical, 
     ViewAngle -> Dynamic@angle] & /@ {{EdgeForm[
      AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
     Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 2]}, {EdgeForm[
      Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[2], 
        AbsoluteDashing[{1, 9}, 0, "Round"]}], FaceForm[], 
     Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 2]}}, All, 1]
 ]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the excellent answer of [@LukasLang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289031/72111), we complete the animation。

```
Animate[DynamicModule[{point = 10 {Cos[t], Sin[t], .5}, 
   vertical = {0, 0, 1}, angle = 8 Degree}, 
  Overlay[Graphics3D[#, Boxed -> False, 
      Lighting -> DirectionalLight[White, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}], 
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic@point, ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vertical, 
      ViewAngle -> Dynamic@angle] & /@ {{EdgeForm[
       AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
      Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 2]}, {EdgeForm[
       Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[2], 
         AbsoluteDashing[{2, 6}, 0, "Round"]}], FaceForm[], 
      Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 2]}}, All, 1]], {t, 0, 
  2 π, .1}, AnimationRate -> 5]
```

[image]