# How can drawing this cone always show code running?

Tags: graphics3d

[image]

The vertex of the cone is P, the center of the base circle is O, AB is the diameter of the base, the angle APB is 120 degrees, AP=2, point C is on the circumference of the base, and the dihedral angle P-AC-O is 45 degrees

How can drawing this cone always show code running?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r=Sqrt[3];h=1;
o={0,0,0};p={0,0,h};\[Alpha]=180 Degree;
circle[t_]=r {Cos[t],Sin[t],0};
b=circle[0];
a=circle[0+\[Alpha]];
c={x,y,z};
c=SolveValues[{(c-a) . (b-c)==0,Abs[Cos[VectorAngle[Cross[p-a,p-c],Cross[a-o,a-c]]]]==Cos[45 Degree],z==0},{x,y,z}]//First
labels={Text[Style[O,12,FontFamily->"Times"],o,{2,-1}],Text[Style[A,12,FontFamily->"Times"],a,{2,-1}],Text[Style[B,12,FontFamily->"Times"],b,{1,2}],Text[Style[C,12,FontFamily->"Times"],c,{-2,0}],Text[Style[P,12,FontFamily->"Times"],p,{-2,0}]};
cir=ParametricPlot3D[circle[t],{t,0,2 \[Pi]},Mesh->{{\[Pi]}},MeshShading->{Directive@{Dashed,Black},Black}];
dashLines={Dashed,AbsoluteThickness[2],Line[{{o,p},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c}}]};
realLines={AbsoluteThickness[2],Line[{{a,p},{b,p}}]};
boundaryLines={AbsoluteThickness[2],Line[{{a,p},{b,p}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines,realLines,boundaryLines,labels}],cir,Boxed->False,Axes->False,ViewPoint->{-0.29,-3.26,0.84}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Compute the coordinates of point c,the length of the sides `bc` and `ac` and the volume of the cone.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r = Sqrt[3];
h = 1;
o = {0, 0, 0};
c = r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0};
b = {r, 0, 0};
a = {-r, 0, 0};
p = {0, 0, h};
sol = Solve[{VectorAngle[Cross[c - b, a - b], 
       Cross[c - p, a - p]] == π/4, 0 <= t <= π}, t, 
    Reals][[1]];
c = c /. sol // FullSimplify
{bc, ac} = {EuclideanDistance[b, c], EuclideanDistance[a, c]} // 
  FullSimplify
Volume[Cone[{o, p}, r]]
```

[image]

- Animate (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289169/72111)

```
labels = {Text[Style[O, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], o, {2, -1}], 
  Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {2, -1}], 
  Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 2}], 
  Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {-2, 0}], 
  Text[Style[P, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {-2, 0}]};
ani = Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{point = N[10 {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], .2}], 
   vertical = {0, 0, 1}, angle = 7 Degree}, 
  Overlay[Graphics3D[{#, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
      Lighting -> AmbientLight[GrayLevel[.8]], 
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic@point, ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vertical, 
      ViewAngle -> Dynamic@angle] & /@ {{EdgeForm[
       AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
      Cone[{o, p}, r]}, {EdgeForm[
       Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[1], 
         AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}, 0, "Round"]}], FaceForm[], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1], AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}, 0, "Round"], 
      Line[{a, b}], Line[{o, p}], Line[{a, c}], Line[{b, c}], 
      Cone[{o, p}, r]}}, All, 1]], {{θ, 5}, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Comment: Draw this dynamic picture to know that the three points on the bottom surface are not fixed. 
The original code is stuck here to calculate a good result, is an indefinite equation.

Answer (score 5):

```
r = Sqrt[3]; h = 1;
o = {0, 0, 0}; p = {0, 0, h}; \[Alpha] = 180 Degree;
circle[t_] = r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0};
b = circle[0];
a = circle[0 + \[Alpha]];
cc = {x, y, z};
c = SolveValues[{(cc - a) . (b - cc) == 0, 
     ComplexExpand@
       Abs[Cos[VectorAngle[Cross[p - a, p - cc], 
          Cross[a - o, a - cc]]]] == Cos[45 Degree], z == 0}, {x, y, 
     z}] // First;
labels = {Text[Style[O, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], o, {2, -1}], 
   Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {2, -1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 2}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[P, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {-2, 0}]};
cir = ParametricPlot3D[circle[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Mesh -> {{\[Pi]}}, 
   MeshShading -> {Directive@{Dashed, Black}, Black}];
dashLines = {Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{{o, p}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}]};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{a, p}, {b, p}}]};
boundaryLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{a, p}, {b, p}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, boundaryLines, labels}], cir, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {-0.29, -3.26, 0.84}]
```

[image]

Comment: ```Volume[ConvexHullRegion[{a,b,c,o,p}]]```It is not possible to determine the volume of the cone using this code. How can I use it to determine the volume of the cone?

Comment: (1) Cone ≠ convex hull of five points. (2) V(cone) = ${1\over3}\pi r^2h$.

Comment: @csn899 - `Volume[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, r]]`

Answer (score 4):

You are nearly there, your code is nearly o.k. What is missing is, to let MMA know, that you are only interested in real solutions.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r = Sqrt[3]; h = 1;
o = {0, 0, 0}; p = {0, 0, h}; \[Alpha] = 180 Degree;
circle[t_] = r {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0};
b = circle[0];
a = circle[0 + \[Alpha]];
c = {x, y, z};
c = SolveValues[{(c - a) . (b - c) == 0, 
    Abs[Cos[VectorAngle[Cross[p - a, p - c], Cross[a - o, a - c]]]] ==
      Cos[45 Degree], z == 0, {x, y, z} \[Element] Reals}, {x, y, 
    z}] // First
labels = {Text[Style[O, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], o, {2, -1}], 
   Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {2, -1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 2}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[P, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {-2, 0}]};
cir = ParametricPlot3D[circle[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Mesh -> {{\[Pi]}}, 
   MeshShading -> {Directive@{Dashed, Black}, Black}];
dashLines = {Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{{o, p}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}]};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{a, p}, {b, p}}]};
boundaryLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{a, p}, {b, p}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, boundaryLines, labels}], cir, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {-0.29, -3.26, 0.84}]
```

[image]