# Plot one set of "x" with at least three sets of "y" in different scale

Tags: plotting, scaling

I'm sorry if the question is too obvious, but I haven't been able to find a straight answer for Mathematica.

I have 1 set of "x" with at least 3 sets of "y" in different scales. I need to plot them together but I cannot find a way to offset the third "y" axis so that it is "out" of the main frame. Producing plots separately and putting them together with `ImagePadding` works wonderfully for 2 sets of "y" data, but I cannot find a similar solution for 3 sets which require different scales.

This is what I have:

[image: what_i_have]

This is more or less what I need:

[image: what_i_need]

Is there a way that I can shift one of the axis to the right so that they do not overlay?

Thank you

**Edit**

After the answer provided by @bobthechemist, I modified his code to adapt it to the lists I usually work it rather than symbolic functions. The resulting plot is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Edit

Here is a version that avoids the use of `Inset` and instead uses `Overlay`.  I think this version covers all of the OPs requests.  I have not tried to functionalize the code at this point since there will likely be some tweaking of parameters based on the actual functions plotted.

```
optsall = {Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
   BaseStyle -> {Thick, FontSize -> 14}};
opts1 = {ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.11]}, {Scaled[0.04],
       Scaled[0.02]}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Thick, {Thick, Blue}, Thick, Opacity[0]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "First y-label"}};
opts2 = {ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.11]}, {Scaled[0.04],
       Scaled[0.02]}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity@0, Opacity@0, Green},
   FrameTicks -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> ConstantArray["Second y-label", 4]};
opts3 = {ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[0.11], Scaled[0.05]}, {Scaled[0.04],
       Scaled[0.02]}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity@0, Opacity@0, Red},
   FrameTicks -> All, FrameLabel -> ConstantArray["Third y-label", 4]};
Overlay[{
  Plot[{x, Rescale[x^2, {0, 100}, {0, 10}], 
      Rescale[x^3, {0, 1000}, {0, 10}]}, {x, 0, 10},
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red},
     ##, PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[{"y = x", "y = x^2", "y = x^3"}, 
        LegendFunction -> (Framed[#] &)], Scaled[{0.15, 0.8}]]] & @@ 
   Join[optsall, opts1],
  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> None,
     ##] & @@ Join[optsall, opts2],
  Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> None, ##] & @@ 
   Join[optsall, opts3]

  }]
```

[image]

Combining `Overlay` with `ImagePadding` allowed me to avoid some resizing problems with `Inset`.  I received a little bit of inspiration from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6486/7167) which allowed me to organize the options nicely.

### Old version, since this is the one that was accepted as the answer

Here is my attempt, which should be considered a work in progress.  There are some things I want to add, but I also have to do some chores.  I figured an incomplete answer to whet one's whistle is better than none.

```
Clear[threeyaxisplot];
threeyaxisplot[{f1_, f1label_}, {f2_, f2label_}, {f3_, f3label_}, 
  range : {var_Symbol, vmin_?NumericQ, vmax_?NumericQ}] := 
 Module[{plot1, plot2, plot3, p1yrng, p2yrng, p3yrng, p2yaxis, 
   p3yaxis},
  {
   {plot1, plot2, plot3} = 
    Plot[#[var], range, Axes -> False, 
       Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
       PlotRangeClipping -> False] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
   };
  {p2yaxis, p3yaxis} = 
   Plot[(First@#)[var], range, Axes -> False, 
      Frame -> {False, True, False, False}, PlotStyle -> White, 
      FrameLabel -> {None, Last@#}] & /@ {{f2, f2label}, {f3, 
      f3label}};
  {p1yrng, p2yrng, p3yrng} = 
   Last@(PlotRange /. Options[#, PlotRange]) & /@ {plot1, plot2, 
     plot3};
  Plot[{f1[var], Rescale[f2[var], p2yrng, p1yrng], 
    Rescale[f3[var], p3yrng, p1yrng]}, range,
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   Axes -> False, Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
   FrameLabel -> {None, f1label},
   Epilog -> {
     Inset[p2yaxis, Scaled@{1.6, 0.5}, Scaled@{0.5, 0.5}, Scaled@1.07],
     Inset[p3yaxis, Scaled@{1.85, 0.5}, Scaled@{0.5, 0.5}, 
      Scaled@1.07]}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 130}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
  ]
out = threeyaxisplot[{# &, "function1"}, {#^2 &, "function2"}, {#^3 &,
    "function3"}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

My approach is to plot all three functions on the same axes using `Rescale` and then take the original axis from the 2nd and 3rd plots and use `Inset` to place them on this rescaled plot.  There's some tweaking that needs to be done:

- Using the right-hand frame as opposed to the left-hand frame for axes 2 and 3 should make the formatting of the right hand axes more traditional
- The colors of the 2nd and 3rd axes should be changed to match the plot colors
- `threeyaxisplot` needs some work in the function definition.  For example, I cannot currently write `threeyaxisplot[{x, "label"},{x^2,"label"}....]` and need to pass pure functions instead.

I plan on addressing these after the chores are done :-)