# Is it possible to have more than two vertical axis in Mathematica 2D plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics, scaling

Is it possible to have more than two vertical axis in Mathematica 2D plots?

This is possible for example in matplotlib (plotting library for Python):

http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html

EDIT:

the only pitfall of the given answer in the linked question is that the figure cannot be resized, zoomed in/out and axis cannot be edited - when compared to the example that I provided in matplotlib link.

Comment: Use `Frame -> True, Axes -> False`. This gives two vertical and two horizontal axes, like in the Matlab plot. To label them, you will need to specify `FrameLabel -> etc.` instead of `AxesLabel -> etc.`.

Comment: the question asks for more than 2 vertical axis, e.g. see the link

Comment: LOL I'm stupid, never mind.

Comment: So I checked the `Axes` and `AxesLabel` documentation and found no instances of using three different vertical axes (unless I'm missing something). It might be possible to hard-code another axis in, but it might be a bit kludgy. Hopefully there is a built-in way that someone is aware of.

Comment: same finding with me

Comment: relate Q/A: [Plot one set of “x” with at least three sets of “y” in different scale](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58508/125)

Comment: this is what I was looking for, the only drawback is readability and extension to more than 3 axis in the linked answer

Comment: @denfromufa If the linked Q&A is what you need we should close this question as a duplicate, or if it is not you should clearly state how your needs differ from the existing answers there in an edit to your question.

Comment: @denfromufa my answer to the linked question could be extended to any (practical) number of vertical axes; note that the `optx` symbols and the `Plot` commands in the Overlay could readily be Mapped with a bit of tweaking.

Comment: @bobthechemist I believe that your example can be extended

Comment: the only pitfall of the given answer in the linked question is that the figure cannot be resized, zoomed in/out and axis cannot be edited - when compared to the example that I provided in matplotlib link.

Comment: you could also try [MATLink](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10231/125)

Comment: it would be easier to call matplotlib using python, not matlink :)