# How to show both big numbers and small numbers in figure?

Tags: plotting

```
data1 = {{10, 0.336326}, {20, 0.382843}, {50, 0.53543}, {100, 0.686378}, {200, 0.784768}};
data2 = {{10, 0.000174682}, {20, 0.000143662}, {50, 0.000102721}, {100, 0.000151156}, {200, 0.000159283}};
data3= {{10, 0.00005875}, {20, 0.000055}, {50, 0.000055}, {100, 0.00010375}, {200, 0.000125}};
```

I am now using `ListPlot`,

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.000001, 0.8}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[ LineLegend[{"data1", "data2", "data3"}], {After, Right}] ]
```

I get the following figure. However, `data2` and `data3` are too small to see. How should I deal with this situation? Particularly, how to adjust the `y-ticks` to show all the data in a more readable way? Is it possible to use non-uniform `y-ticks` in `ListPlot`?

[image: list-plot]

Comment: Related [Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/5414)

Comment: You could possibly use [multiple axes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58514/7167).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use ListPlot, then perhaps you should make two or three separate plots and align them one atop the other.  A better way is to use ListLogPlot, however:

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2, data3}, Joined -> True, 
     PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, PlotRange -> {0.000001, 0.8}, 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[{"data1", "data2", "data3"}], {After, Right}]]
```

Comment: @Sektor Is it possible to use non-uniform `y-ticks` in `ListPlot`?

Comment: I realized that it is still the original data that is plotted in the `ListLogPlot`. So `ListLogPlot` is OK here. However, if my data contains zeros, how to show them in `ListLogPlot` (`Log[0]` is not defined)?