# Dual Axis Histogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

I'd like to plot two histograms on top of one another, but they have very different scales. Is it possible to plot a histogram with two y-axes, similar to the custom function found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html) for plots?

Comment: You can also plot a pdf `Histogram[{d1, d2}, Automatic, "PDF"]` but then you have to handle FrameTicks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More or less a [duplicate of this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58514/7167), but just to demonstrate how it is used:

Some data:

```
d1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
d2 =  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];
```

Create the individual plots and then combine them using `Overlay`

```
optsall = {Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
   BaseStyle -> {Thick, FontSize -> 14}};
opts1 = {ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.11]}, {Scaled[0.04],
       Scaled[0.02]}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Thick, {Thick, Red}, Thick, Opacity[0]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "First y-label"}, 
   ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Red]};
opts2 = {ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.11]}, {Scaled[0.04],
       Scaled[0.02]}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity@0, Opacity@0, Blue}, 
   FrameTicks -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> ConstantArray["Second y-label", 4], 
   ChartStyle -> Blue};
Histogram[d1, Join[optsall, opts1]];
Histogram[d2, Join[optsall, opts2]];
Overlay[{%, %%}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]