# How i can Overlay two histograms

Tags: plotting, histograms

```
Tabla = 1/100 {56, 55, 51, 45, 54, 50, 45, 57, 55, 41, 43, 46, 43, 53,
   56, 53, 52, 61, 52, 54, 56, 46, 61, 43, 54, 52, 53, 50, 50, 50, 
   44, 51, 60, 60, 53, 54, 53, 45, 41, 54, 52, 51, 64, 60, 65, 56, 51,
   53, 54, 48, 52, 48, 61, 54, 58, 49, 46, 50, 48, 58, 46, 49, 47, 
   54, 56, 62, 53, 54, 54, 54, 53, 48, 54, 45, 49, 54, 51, 47, 53, 54,
   53, 45, 48, 49, 57, 56, 55, 59, 56, 55, 46, 45, 54, 53, 52, 47, 
   46, 48, 45, 47};
```

I have  following histograms:

```
Histogram[Tabla, AxesLabel -> {"tempo (s)", "frequência"}]

Histogram[Tabla, 6, "Probability", AxesOrigin -> {0.706, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {None, "frequência relativa"}]
```

I want to overlay them and get one histogram with 2 axes, one axe to left and other to right.

I try with:

```
Histogram[Tabla, AxesLabel -> {"tempo (s)", "frequência"}, Axes -> {False, True}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[Histogram[Tabla, 6, "Probability", AxesOrigin -> {0.706, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"tempo (s)", "frequência relativa"}]]]
```

Help me  please.

Comment: `Show[Histogram[Tabla],Histogram[Tabla,6,"Probability",ChartStyle->Blue]`

Comment: If you really want to `Overlay` them, check [Dual Axis Histogram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78544/18476).

Answer (score 4):

You can get both as one `Historam` with custom right `FrameTicks`:

```
ticks = Join[
   Transpose[{#, ConstantArray[Null, Length@#]}] &@Range[0, 42, 2],
   {#, N@#/Length@Tabla} & /@ Range[0, 40, 10]] /. (0.) -> 0

Histogram[Tabla, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"frequência", "frequência relativa"}, {"tempo (s)", None}},   
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, ticks}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image: Out]