# How can I save as PDF without file size getting too large?

Tags: pdf-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graphics exported from Mathematica 9 are very large because even standard fonts are embedded](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/graphics-exported-from-mathematica-9-are-very-large-because-even-standard-fonts)

I have a text only notebook that I saved as PDF.  The file size is 2.8 mb.  The actual notebook is 12 kb.  There are no graphics or special fonts.  Is there a way to get a PDF file without the file size being so large?

Comment: what version of _Mathematica_ are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 9.

Comment: But Mathematica 8 save as PDF also produces a large file relative to the actual content.  Mathematica 8 produced a 350 kb file with 1 line of text in it.  This is ridiculously high.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  I think you are right.  This can question can be closed.