# How can I convert a plot to pdf or eps without errors?

Tags: plotting, version-9

*Mathematica* 9.0.1, Linux. I try to save a plot as a pdf. I tried four different options. In each case some errors appeared as blank space

[image: image 1]

( http://yadi.sk/d/h1koyDci4z3rc ). I also tried to save as eps. Another problem appeared -- there is no half letter on the Labels:

[image: image 2]

(see here http://yadi.sk/d/OBRDmp3z4z42U ). The same figures are saved very well in *Mathematica* 7 without an error. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Convert to bmp and png works well, without errors.

Comment: I've added your images. Could you please include the code to reproduce the plots? See the [help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for how to format code.

Comment: The same problem appears for simple graphics like this:
Plot[{ x^2, x^5}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["B", FontSize -> 25], 
   Style["A", Italic, FontSize -> 25]}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.002]}, {Black, Thickness[0.005]}}]

Comment: I tried it on a Linux server with version 8 and could not reproduce the problem. The output of `Export["p.pdf",%]` looks identical to that in the notebook. I don't have version 9 on Linux, so I can't check any further, unfortunately.

Comment: On Linux v9, `Export["p.pdf",%]` works for the simple $x^2$ and $x^5$ graphic. Left-clicking the graphic, then right-clicking Save Graphic As... also works. Clicking the cell bracket of the graphic, then clicking File > Save Selection As fails, producing a blank white *.pdf file.

Comment: @Jens: How did you get fonts to work in PDF export?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail It worked out of the box. The linux server isn't under my control, so I'm not sure about the font related details of the Mathematica installation.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Could you explain me where are these fonts to work in PDF export? In menu "Save Selection As" there is no point about fonts.

Comment: @KennyColnago Did you use a specific options when you export to pdf? I used Export["p.pdf",%] as you, but obtain the same result - blank horizontal stripe. The problem appears only with pdf and eps formats, it may be indeed connects with some fonts.

Comment: @nail  I did not use any specific options when exporting to pdf.

Comment: I solved this problem by using http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/graphics-exported-from-mathematica-9-are-very-large-because-even-standard-fonts . In option inspector I set EmbedExternalFonts -> False and EmbedStandardPostScriptFonts -> False. In this case left click and save as works well, but Export["file.pdf",%] works bad.