# Awful styling in MMA10's Plot

Tags: plotting, export, version-10, style, eps-format

Switching to MMA10, I'd want to produce a plot using this code:

```
pad = 100;
Fig8 = 
 Plot[{2 p3[x], p2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Dashed, Gray}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.6, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Froeschlé HE", "Chirikov mLE"}, {"Chirikov mLE", "Froeschlé mLE"}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"Chirikov map", "2D Froeschlé map"}, 
   LegendLabel -> Placed["p(x)", Above], 
   LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMargins -> 1, 
   LabelStyle -> 5], {0.65, 0.4}], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, "0.2"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.6, 
   "0.6"}, {0.8, "0.8"}, {1.0, "1.0"}}, {{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, 
   "0.1"}, {0.4, "0.2"}, {0.6, "0.3"}, {0.8, "0.4"}, {1.0, 
   "0.5"}}}, {{{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, "0.2"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.6, 
   "0.6"}, {0.8, "0.8"}, {1.0, "1.0"}}, {{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, 
   "0.1"}, {0.4, "0.2"}, {0.6, "0.3"}, {0.8, "0.4"}, {1.0, 
   "0.5"}}}}, ImagePadding -> {{pad, pad}, {All, All}}]`
```

(Feel free to change the functions `p2[x]` and `p3[x]` to whatever you want)

This is generally the same approach I used since MMA7 and 'should' look nice. However, the output is unacceptable:

```
Export["Fig_8.eps",Fig8]
```

[image]

compared to a .pdf file:

`Export["Fig_8.pdf",Fig8]`

[image]

Although I can convert the .pdf to .eps and it still looks ok, but this is not the case. Why does the .eps look so horrible in MMA10?

**EDIT**

To clarify: I don't want to get back to styling from older versions. I want the labels (axes and legend) not to be padded with randomly distributed spaces, e.g. bottom label should be "Chirikov mLE", not "Chi ri kovm LE" as it is. And the distances between letters in "Froeschle" seem to be too small. Compare the above screen shots from my `Export`ed .eps and .pdf files.

Moreover, reading threads related to the one mentioned by Mr.Wizard, I have an impression that this lack of functionality comes from new underlying mechanism of `Export` in MMA10. The question is, can anyone figure out a workaround?

**EDIT 2**

I'm using Scientific Linux 6.

Comment: Is your issue only with the EPS output or the appearance of the plot in the Front End as well?

Comment: I like the thinly disguised quip at @rm-rf: "Froeschlé" or "Fröschle" means "little frog" in Suebian :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard only the .eps output; in the notebook itself everything looks fine.

Comment: Other v10 EPS problems noted here: [(56779)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56779/121)

Comment: You can copy and run the following at the beginning of the NB? `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]` Is there an improvement?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I read the thread, but changing EmbedExternalFonts and EmbedStandardPostScriptFonts to False does not change anything. The .eps output still has those nasty spacings; my issue are not the fonts themselves, but rather their arrangement.

Comment: @Lou No, that doesn't change a bit...

Comment: I did not mean to imply that thread had a solution; I was only providing links for organization.  I am sorry that I do not know a solution to your problem.

Comment: I had the same issue several time in pdf while exporting with Linux. So it is a linux issue that has been here for a very long time.

Comment: @Öskå I'm using Scientific Linux 6 and as indicated don't have problems with .pdf, only with .eps

Comment: Your code produced this on Mac OSX 10.10.1, *Mma* V10.0.1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/f2QMV.png  (The viewer in Mac converts the EPS to PDF in order to display it.) It seems fairly acceptable. It's not surprising, I suppose, that font issues are system dependent.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes indeed, that's how I'd like my plot to look like. So, hm, it's not simply an MMA10 issue, but the problem is how MMA10 cooperates with certain OS. So I suppose no fixing it as it stands and I'll have to stick to converting .pdf to .eps :(

Comment: @corey979 Have you tried `Export["Fig_8.eps", First@ImportString[ExportString[Fig8, "PDF"]]]`, or perhaps that is what you wish to avoid.  You can make it into a function, so that it's not terribly inconvenient. I would say that it is also possible that certain OS don't do their fonts correctly. That's my experience as an end-user.

Comment: I'm not seeing the font-spacing problem when with *Mathematica* 10.0.1 under Mac OS X 10.9.5 I export to EPS, even without font-embedding, and when I view the exported file in either GhostView for Mac or Graphic Converter. In each app, I do believe I'm directly viewing the EPS and *not* a conversion to PDF.

Comment: @MichaelE2 that works perfect! That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Post a full answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On some computer systems, the OS & *Mathematica* seem not handle fonts properly when exporting to EPS. I am not able to check all systems, but it is possible that converting an expression to PDF first and then to EPS might work.  Importing the PDF shows that the font glyphs in the image you get have been converted to *Mathematica* graphics primitives (`FilledCurve` usually).  Exporting the graphics to EPS should work on all systems.  The only possible hitch is whether the fonts were rendered properly in the PDF conversion and import.

Code:

```
Export["Fig_8.eps", First@ImportString[ExportString[Fig8, "PDF"]]]
```

General-use function:

```
exportViaPDF[file_String, expr_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
 Export[file, 
  First@ImportString[
    ExportString[expr, "PDF", "PDFOptions" /. {opts} /. "PDFOptions" -> {}]],
  opts]
```

It's hard to set defaults for options to `Export`.  See [Pass Options to Export[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15272/pass-options-to-export).  On the other `Export` is very forgiving of options that make no sense.  It seems to ignore them.

Side note: In some random testing, I found the default PDF option setting `"AllowRasterization" -> Automatic` leads to error messages when the `expr` is 3D graphics (V10.0.1, Mac OSX 10.10.1):

> Import::general: Unsupported Shading type 7 >>

But both the `True` and `False` settings worked fine.  Example:

```
exportViaPDF["foo.eps", Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
  "PDFOptions" -> {"AllowRasterization" -> True}, ImageSize -> 100]
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to add the option: `PlotTheme->"Classic"`which transforms the plot to the style of MMA7:

```
 pad = 100;
Fig8 = Plot[{2 Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Dashed, Gray}},
   AspectRatio -> 0.6, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Froeschlé HE", "Chirikov mLE"}, {"Chirikov mLE", 
     "Froeschlé mLE"}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"Chirikov map", "2D Froeschlé map"}, 
     LegendLabel -> Placed["p(x)", Above], LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
     LegendMargins -> 1, LabelStyle -> 5], {0.3, 0.55}], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0.0"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.8, "0.8"}, {1.2, 
       "1.2"}, {1.6, "1.6"}}, {{0, "0.0"}, {0.4, "0.2"}, {0.8, 
       "0.4"}, {1.2, "0.6"}, {1.6, "0.8"}, {2, "1"}}}, {{{0, 
       "0.0"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.8, "0.8"}, {1.0, "1.0"}}, {{0, 
       "0.0"}, {0.4, "0.2"}, {0.8, "0.4"}, {1.2, "0.6"}}}}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{pad, pad}, {All, All}}]
```

The result should look like the following:

[image]

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain more precisely.

Have fun!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. The problem with my Export to .eps is that the upper label is slightly cut from above, and that the spacings between letters are completely misaligned. The bottom label should be "Chirikov mLE", but it looks like "Chi ri kovm LE"; note also extremely big spacings in the legend. When I Export to .pdf everything looks ok and in the Front End also everything is fine. So there's a bug connected with exporting to .eps

Comment: @corey979 These are two separate questions. The first is how to achieve the style like in Mma7, and the second is how to export to eps. Above I only answered the first one. Concerning the second there were several discussions here. May be it is worth having a look. My feeling is that there are some problems with the exporting to eps in Mma9 amd 10. I, however, often successfully do such an export to later use the images as illustrations for journal publications. My trick is to first rasterize the image: `Rasterize[Fig8,RasterSize->1000] `. Try this, it might help.