# Y axis cut off when exporting eps

Tags: plotting

I am plotting this:

```
 Show[ BarChart[{180, 1, 1}, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}, ChartStyle -> {Blue}], 
 BarChart[{15, 0, 0}, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}, ChartStyle -> {Red}]]
```

and what I see in mathematica is:

[image]

and this is what i see when i export in eps (don't mind the gray):

[image]

As you can see, the y-axis disappears. However, if i export as pdf it is ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Export["plot.eps", First@ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"]]]`. If not, check [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71408/22013).

Comment: Tnx, this works. But why does it work? Or, why doesn't simple export work?

Comment: Not really sure; maybe check the link for some hints.

Comment: You should add your version info, on OSX with MMA v.10.0.1.0 I don't have this problem.