# Text added on a plot changes the style

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have some troubles whenever I add a text on a plot. When I save the figure in a ".ps" format, I get some weird images, as in the example. [image]

The figure is normally displayed within Mathematica. The problem only occurs when I try to save the figure as an image.

Comment: can you provide the code you used?

Comment: Be sure you have all the necessary .ps fonts installed.

Comment: Related: [(70215)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70215/awful-styling-in-mma10s-plot).