# Using high RasterSize or ImageResolution changes contour pattern

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I found that the detailed contour pattern will be altered if we `Rasterize` the original graphics using high `RasterSize` or `ImageResolution`. Here is an example:

```
g = ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
       Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Range[min, max, 0.01]],
       ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[.3], Thickness[.002]],
       ImageSize -> 500]
```

which looks like

[image]

Now we `Rasterize` g using four times its original pixel size

```
dim = ImageDimensions@Rasterize[g];
Rasterize[g, RasterSize -> 4*dim]
```

and we obtain

[image]

So the patterns of the contour lines are different. I firstly think that this problem can be solved by increasing the `Thinckness` value in `ContourStyle`, but this will not make the result better. I wonder if we can improve it?

---

**Update**

As a workaround, can we try to preserve the pattern by keeping the contour in vectot format (together with axis and ticks), and only `Rasterize` the background? In this case I think there might be problems with the thickness of contour lines.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern

Comment: @rm -rf, As how I understand the article, the triangle moire pattern in my example is caused by representing a contour line using more pixels, and the intersections prevails the original pattern. I still do not understand why such intersections can happen since the pixels should always be aligned...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key point of Moiré pattern is the **ratio** of the "pixel" size of your underlying raster grid and the distance of your contour lines. So if you want to get a similar pattern on a finer grid, you need to increase your `Contours` to insure an invariant ratio.

```
g = ContourPlot[
   Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
   PlotPoints -> 10,
   ContourShading -> None,
   Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Range[min, max, 0.03]],
   ContourStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.7], Thickness[0]],
   ImageSize -> 200];
rg = Rasterize[g, RasterSize -> 200]
```

[image: moire pattern 1]

```
Block[{magnif = 2.5},
 g2 = ContourPlot[
   Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
   PlotPoints -> Round[10 magnif],
   ContourShading -> None,
   Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Range[min, max, 0.03/magnif]],
   ContourStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.7], Thickness[0]],
   ImageSize -> Round[200 magnif]];
 dim = ImageDimensions[rg];
 Rasterize[g2,
  RasterSize -> Round[magnif dim],
  ImageSize -> Round[200 magnif]]
 ]
```

[image: moire pattern 2]

Comment: This works, thank you for pointing out the key  reason!

Comment: @saturasl You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

The lines on your plot go too close to each other and as a result one pixel on the screen should contain more than one line. Apart of image size, the resulting appearance in such cases is also hugely affected by antialiasing which is `True` by default:

```
Rasterize[Style[g, Antialiasing -> False], "Image", RasterSize -> 4*dim]
```

[image]

### UPDATE

Answering the "Update" section in the question. If you can work with vector formats you do not need to rasterize anything, just `Export` as `PDF`. [You can be confused](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/GM___ryfa34/9ETqnWt5bcMJ) by [huge size of the generated file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1542/280) and [by little artifacts at the boundaries of the polygons](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4DB7CD30.6030906@hccnet.nl&forum_name=inkscape-user). Both problems can be solved using the [`FixPolygons` package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7029/) by Will Robertson. It takes some time to merge adjacent polygons but the result renders nicely. Here is how it looks in Acrobat 11 after `Export`ing from *Mathematica* 8.0.4 (the colors are wrong, *Mathematica* 9 probably will generate a file with better colors because it embeds colorspace information):

[image: screenshot]

For producing such PDF file you need to copy the `FixPolygons.m` file to the "Mathematica/Applications" directory in your user profile and evaluate the following:

```
<< FixPolygons`
g2 = g // FixPolygons
Export["test.pdf", g2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, the problem is clear now. Your suggestion makes a good start, and the result is improved, but there is still obvious difference...

Comment: I decide to accept Silvia's answer because it directly solves the original problem. But I also want to express my appreciation for your answer, it will be useful in future!