# Why the complicated pattern in this 3D plot?

Tags: plotting

```
ListPointPlot3D[
Table[{n, s, (Prime[n]^s/(Prime[n]^s - 1))}, {n, 1, 2000}, {s, 2, 80}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Is the pattern the result of the data, the plotting function, or a bit of both?

**Edit** fixed bad exponents, replaced the plot.

Comment: It seems to be [Moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

Comment: @Kuba, perfect! Make it an answer and I'll sign off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is [Moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

Closely related topic with 2D case: [Using high RasterSize changes contour pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38271/5478)

Worth to add that the patterns does not seem to have a translation symmetry because the projection is not parallel. You can compare it with distant `ViewPoint` case:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[{n, s, (Prime[n]^s/(Prime[n]^s - 1))}, {n, 1, 2000}, {s, 2, 
   80}], PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> 1000 {1, -1, 1}, 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]