# QuantilePlot silliness

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

When I do a quantile plot of two large data sets (in my case, each of them of size around 3 million), the resulting notebook cell is huge, and if you save it as PDF, the resulting PDF is 13MB in size. These things are so large that they choke Acrobat X Pro (it runs out of memory when trying to optimize them). Now, firstly, this is clearly a bug (it is a *plot*, so there is absolutely no reason to plot 3 million points, unless you want to show it to beings from Alpha Centauri), the questions are: has it always been thus, or is it a new bug, and (assuming I am not the first to run into this problem), what is the best work around you have found? (one can downsample the data before plotting, but that throws away information).

**EXAMPLE** This example is obviously bad, because in this case downsampling will change absolutely nothing, but it should show off the problem.

**And By the way** Since the files are too huge to be optimized or printed by Acrobat, the only solution I found was to do a screen grab (with Skitch) - thank God for Retina display, since that at least produces a decent res. Pretty gross, though.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {3000000}]
QuantilePlot[data, data]
```

(prepare to get a coffee while this is running, and save all work :()

Comment: Could you supply a toy example to check on different versions and reproduce your problem?

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file), although perhaps you've read it already.

Comment: @YvesKlett Sure, take a look at the edit.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus It is clearly related, but I am assuming there is some different mechanism, since in the example you linked to, it is hard to even imagine why the thing is so huge, whereas in my example I can think of a mechanism....

Comment: Perhaps a non-trivial example (plus semicolon after the first line) would really be more useful. What kind of plot would you rather prefer?

Comment: @IgorRivin: I don't totally understand the internal structure of Mathematica graphics, but in the case of  `QuantilePlot`, executing `FullForm` on some of the Documentation example plots shows that it's just a `Graphics` object with `Point[(*bunch of point coordinates*)]`. So it's probably taking your input and cheerfully spitting out a `Point` expression with 3 million points. Does `Rasterize`ing the plot help?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I did not know about `Rasterize[]`, can't hurt to try :) However, you would think that it (MMA) would do the right thing before producing the PDF!

Comment: Versions 9.01 and 10.01 produce about the same output. 3mio pts in -> 3mio pts out...

Comment: @Du7mpsterDoofus Rasterize does work! The bad news is that with `ImageResolution->200` the tick labels are noticeably fuzzier (which is weird, since my monitor is nowhere near 200dpi). I suppose the good news is that if you ask Acrobat to then optimize scanned document, it will probably sharpen them back up.

Comment: Try to add in `Magnify` before rasterization.

Comment: @Igor Rivin, can you try: `Map[SetOptions[#, 
    Prolog -> {{EdgeForm[], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
       Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> #] &[{{0, 0}, {1, 
          0}, {1, 1}}]}}] &, {QuantilePlot}];` with `data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {3000000}];
im1 = QuantilePlot[data, data, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, 10}}]` and `Export["myFig3.pdf", im1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file size is considerably smaller (factor of 25+ with 300,000 data points) with use of the `QuantilePlot` option `Joined->True`

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {300000}];

fbc1 = FileByteCount[Export[
    "/Users/hanlonr/Desktop/Mma Temp/qPlot1.pdf", QuantilePlot[data, data]]] //
   Timing
```

> {15.540274, 5528588}

```
fbc2 = FileByteCount[
   Export["/Users/hanlonr/Desktop/Mma Temp/qPlot2.pdf", 
    QuantilePlot[data, data, Joined -> True]]] // Timing
```

> {13.489229, 200718}

```
fbc1/fbc2 // N
```

> {1.15205, 27.5441}

Comment: Wow, who would have thunk it!

Answer (score 6):

Of course, you can `Resterize` and `Export` as it was pointed in comments. However let us do something less trivial. I propose to reduce the number of points and don't lose benefits of the vector format.

I don't wont to drink the coffee at evening so I use smaller number of points

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {100000}];
p = QuantilePlot[data, data]
```

[image]

```
ByteCount[p]
(* 1607504 *)
```

We can span points to a fine grid and delete duplicates

```
p2 = p /. Point[pts_] /; Length[pts] > 100 :> Point@DeleteDuplicates@Round[pts, 0.01]
```

[image]

There is no visible difference but the size is sufficiently smaller

```
ByteCount[p2]
(* 19760 *)
```

Comment: That's a nice method, but what is the advantage over the `Rasterize[]` approach (I see one: it does not screw up the ticks, etc  - is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @IgorRivin Not only. You can zoom the vector figures and see small details. Also I often make some manual post-processing in a vector editor to obtain publication quality figures (tuning dashing of the lines, adding some arrows and LaTeX formulas, etc.).