# vector graphics of a ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

My problem is quite simple and yet I can't seem to find a solution to it. I'm trying to create a figure in vector format but if I export it to EPS I get a very bad gradient in the colors. If I export it to PDF I get a raster image. Somehow I thought to combine both separately (get the lines and spheres in vector and the gradient in raster), but I can't seem to get it to work as the result should look as in the last command:

```
nodelist = {{0, 6.75, 0}, {-0.8, 4.5, 0}, {1.75, 4.6, 0}, {-2.2, 7., 
    0}, {0.3, 8.75, 0}, {2.75, 7.3, 0}, {-2., 0.8, 0}, {0.75, 0.7, 
    0}, {3.25, 1, 0}, {-4.3, 2.3, 0}, {-1.5, 2.5, 0}, {1.8, 2.75, 
    0}, {5.5, 1.75, 0}, {4.25, 3, 0}, {-5.7, 4.1, 0}, {-3, 4.5, 
    0}, {4, 4.75, 0}, {7.1, 4, 0}, {7.75, 6.25, 0}, {-6.5, 6.25, 
    0}, {-4.5, 7.25, 0}, {5.75, 6.5, 0}, {7.5, 7.75, 0}, {-6.38, 8.75,
     0}, {4.75, 8.6, 0}, {-2., 9.5, 0}, {2.75, 10, 0}, {5.5, 11, 
    0}, {-4.125, 11, 0}, {0.5, 10.8, 0}, {-1.7, 12.1, 0}, {2.3, 12.25,
     0}};
nodes = Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], 
   Table[Point[nodelist[[i]]], {i, 32}]}]
```

[image]

```
extruded = {{0, 6.75, 10}, {-0.8, 4.5, 10}, {1.75, 4.6, 10}, {-2.2, 
    7., 10}, {0.3, 8.75, 10}, {2.75, 7.3, 10}, {-2., 0.8, 0}, {0.75, 
    0.7, 0}, {3.25, 1, 0}, {-4.3, 2.3, 0}, {-1.5, 2.5, 0}, {1.8, 2.75,
     0}, {5.5, 1.75, 0}, {4.25, 3, 0}, {-5.7, 4.1, 0}, {-3, 4.5, 
    0}, {4, 4.75, 0}, {7.1, 4, 0}, {7.75, 6.25, 0}, {-6.5, 6.25, 
    0}, {-4.5, 7.25, 0}, {5.75, 6.5, 0}, {7.5, 7.75, 0}, {-6.38, 8.75,
     0}, {4.75, 8.6, 0}, {-2., 9.5, 0}, {2.75, 10, 0}, {5.5, 11, 
    0}, {-4.125, 11, 0}, {0.5, 10.8, 0}, {-1.7, 12.1, 0}, {2.3, 12.25,
     0}};
top = ListPlot3D[{{0, 6.75, 10}, {-0.8, 4.5, 10}, {1.75, 4.6, 
    10}, {-2.2, 7., 10}, {0.3, 8.75, 10}, {2.75, 7.3, 10}}, 
  Mesh -> All, ViewPoint -> Top, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> LightBrown]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ListPlot3D[extruded, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> {None}]
```

[image]

```
fn=ListPlot3D[extruded,Mesh->All,PlotStyle->{Opacity[0.8]},ColorFunction->(ColorData[{"DarkTerrain","Reverse"}][#3]&)]
```

[image]

```
fn2=ListPlot3D[extruded,Mesh->All,PlotStyle->None]
```

[image]

**Vector graphics part**

```
plot=Show[fn2,nodes,Axes->False,BoxRatios->{1,1,0.2},Boxed-> False,PlotRange-> All, ViewPoint->{-Pi,-Pi/2,Pi}]
Export["/Users/aaragon/Desktop/ramp.eps",%]
```

[image]

**Raster graphics part**

```
plot=Show[mesh,fn,nodes,top,Axes->False,BoxRatios->{1,1,0.2},Boxed-> False,PlotRange-> All, ViewPoint->{-Pi,-Pi/2,Pi}]
Export["ramp.pdf",plot,"AllowRasterization"->True,ImageSize->360,ImageResolution->600]
```

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file/

Comment: I saw that answer, and if you see the last command is exactly the solution. But the image created is rasterized, not vector graphics.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon Notice that `planemesh` is not defined in your question, so we can't actually run your code. Can you fix this to include its definition? Also, what happens if you don't allow rasterization in the PDF export?