# Is it possible to export 3D plot in EPS and modify it?

Tags: graphics3d, export

I'm trying to export a 3D figure in EPS to then modify in Illustrator. However, it seems that Mathematica creates an image inside of the EPS file, making it impossible to modify it as well as making it pixeleted if one zooms in. I'm creating and exporting the image with the following code:

```
r = 1.2;
rPerf = 0.5;
b = 2.4;
w = 5;
l = w;
oringP = {-l/2, -l/2, 0};

cube1 = Cuboid[oringP, {w/2, l/2, 1}];
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, b + 1}}, r];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 1.5}, {0, 0, b + 1}}, rPerf];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], cube1, cyl1, cyl2,
                AspectRatio -> Automatic,
                ImageSize -> 200}, Boxed -> False]
Export["test.eps", %]
```

When zooming I can see the pixels of the image

[image]

Is there a correct way to generate a modifiable EPS file for a 3D structure? I can see that if I generate a text using it, I can modify it correctly.

```
Export["AnotherTest.eps", "This is a test"]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: I think this question has been answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file/). One of the problems is that vector graphics will be exported as a raster. If you increase the resolution of the raster you can improve the quality

Comment: Hi, @Dunlop, thanks! While I agree that the thread talks about the quality of the image (so that if I zoom in I don't see the pixels), it is not the main point of my question (I might need to reformulate it if this is the case). Having an EPS file would allow me to modify the image. One example would be to be able to modify one of the lines in the zoomed image from black to green. That is possible for a 2D image like the one generated by exporting a text line

Comment: In my experience, the most time effective solution is to just commit to raster graphics whenever 3D is involved. You can export it at high resolution, so the result will not look pixelated. As Mathematica gained more advanced 3D capabilities, it gradually lost the ability to export 3D graphics as vector. To answer your question directly: no, it's not possible. This answer _may_ not be technically accurate in all situations, but chasing vector graphics will just waste your time here. I gave up on it many years ago.

Comment: You may set the `"AllowRasterization" -> False` option (see documentation). I don't know if it does anything in the current version. I expect it won't help you.