# Saner alternative to ContourPlot fill

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I am producing a large number of `ContourPlot` objects, which when exported generate [notoriously large PDF files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps) because it basically generates lots of little triangles (and on top of that, there are aliasing issues, which can be dealt with as in the linked post).

So, I'm trying to find a way to deal with it in a robust manner. I compare this:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, Contours -> Table[c, {c, -2.2, 2.2, 0.2}]]
```

which gives a 836 kilobytes PDF (here rendered with Mac OS Preview):

[image]

to some homemade code (most of it lifted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/644/how-can-all-those-tiny-polygons-generated-by-regionplot-be-joined-into-a-single/646#646)):

```
graph[expr_, level_, color_] := Module[{g, lines},
  g = RegionPlot[expr < level, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> None];
  lines = Cases[Normal[g], _Line, Infinity];
  Return[{
    EdgeForm@Directive[Black, Thickness[Medium]],
    FaceForm@Directive[Opacity[1], color],
    FilledCurve[List /@ lines]
    }];
  ]

Graphics[Flatten[
  Reverse[Table[
    graph[Cos[x] + 1.1*Sin[y], c, Hue[(c + 2)/4]], {c, -2.2, 2.2, 0.2}]]]]
```

which produces a nice 45 kb PDF:

[image]

---

Now, what's the question? Well, I wonder how I can turn this core idea into a small routine that accepts options, well, just like `ContourPlot` would. I mean, generate axes, accept color options, etc. I don't have any idea where to start, because I'm not really knowledgeable about Mathematica…

Comment: What about rasterizing the contour plot: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953955/optimizing-size-of-eps-pdf-files-generated-by-mathematica

Comment: Note a direct answer, but there is [a tool](http://www-staff.lboro.ac.uk/~mait/personal2/polygone/polygone.html) which can post process the output and remove unnecessary polygons.  I never used it because I don't have a FORTRAN compiler than can compile the code.

Comment: I was thinking about extending that `RegionPlot`-fixer to work with `ContourPlot`, but I didn't need it recently, and it's a bit more complex ... so I didn't do it yet.

Comment: I can't seem to compile polygone with gfortran and I don't really feel like shelling out for the intel fortran compiler. Any one have any experiance with the polygone program?

Comment: @s0rce it seems that polygone requires some F2003 stuff that isn't implemented in gfortran yet (gfortran's F2003 status is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2003Status))

Comment: @F'x Here is an excerpt from an email I got last year from Ian Thompson, the developer of polygone: "Polygone depends rather heavily on certain Fortran 2003 features, which are not yet present in all compilers. The Intel compiler (ifort) and the NAG compiler (nagfor) both support the relevant features. I don't know anything about the Portland compiler, but g95 lacks allocatable character variables, amongst other things. Eliminating these features from the code would probably be very tedious." It also seems too hard to make it work with PDF (i.e., you need to export EPS).

Comment: @s0rce I just tried plygone on two files. In one case it was able to remove many but not all mesh lines. In the second case (exactly the example plot in the question) it unfortunately produced an invalid EPS output file (there are some parameters one can play with, but I tried without success).

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Regardless, in my opinion this is quite a serious bug in the PDF export capabilities of Mathematica.

Comment: @F'x Yes, that's why I said "I don't have a FORTRAN compiler that can compile the code".  If you use Linux (I don't much) you can use Intel's FORTRAN compiler which is free to download.  A colleague used it and compiled it with that.

Comment: I think I posted an improved version of the function that @tkott got started on. See if you like it.

Comment: There is also this method: http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/rasterDensityPlots.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I actually like your own solution as a way to generalize the `RegionPlot` approach, and the answer by @tkott!

**Edit with improved version of RegionPlot trick**

Since @tkott's solution was still rough around the edges, I hacked together a version of it that should be able to emulate all the features of `ContourPlot` - i.e., be usable as a drop-in replacement with the same syntax and options. Here it is:

```
contourRegionPlot[f_, rx_, ry_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{cont, contourOptions, frameOptions, colList, levelList, lab, 
   gr, pOpt, allLines, contourstyle, regionPlotOptions, 
   contourStyleList},
  contourstyle = 
   ContourStyle /. {opts} /. 
     None -> Opacity[0] /. {ContourStyle -> Automatic};
  contourOptions = 
   Join[FilterRules[{opts}, 
     FilterRules[Options[ContourPlot], 
      Except[{Prolog, Epilog, Background, ContourShading, 
        ContourLabels, ContourStyle, RegionFunction}]]], {Background -> None, 
     ContourShading -> True, ContourLabels -> Automatic, 
     ContourStyle -> contourstyle}];
  regionPlotOptions = 
   Join[FilterRules[{opts}, 
     FilterRules[Options[RegionPlot], 
      Except[{Prolog, Epilog, Background,RegionFunction}]]], {Background -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> None}];
  cont = Normal@
    ContourPlot[f, rx, ry, Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, contourOptions]];
  colList = 
   Reverse@Cases[
     cont, {EdgeForm[___], ___, 
       r_?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor, GrayLevel}, 
           Head[#]] &), ___} :> r, Infinity];
  {contourStyleList, levelList} = 
   Transpose@
    Cases[cont, Tooltip[{gr_, __}, lab_] -> {gr, lab}, Infinity];
  frameOptions = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]];
  allLines = 
   Flatten@Prepend[
     Table[RegionPlot[Evaluate[f < levelList[[i]]], rx, ry, 
       Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, regionPlotOptions]], {i, 
       Length[levelList]}], 
     RegionPlot[f > levelList[[-1]], rx, ry, 
      Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, regionPlotOptions]]];
  pOpt = allLines[[1, 2]];
  Show[Graphics[
    MapThread[{EdgeForm[#1], FaceForm@Directive[Opacity[1], #2], 
       FilledCurve[
        List /@ Cases[Normal[#3], _Line, Infinity]]} &, {Append[
       contourStyleList, Opacity[0]], colList, allLines}], pOpt], 
   frameOptions]]
```

**Edit 3**

I streamlined some inefficient code, and made the `ContourStyle` option work. The function  is clearly slower than my rasterized approach. But it comes close to the old version-5 behavior.

**Edit 4**

In the above code, one can now also use `Epilog`, and it is allowed to specify `ContourStyle` as a list with separate directives for each contour.

That's probably all I'll do with this method, since there are sufficiently many alternatives that could be used if the above doesn't do what you want. I personally still prefer the continuous gradients of `DensityPlot` and `contourDensityPlot` (see below). Meanwhile there is also @Szabolcs' answer, which is seen in his example to accept the `RegionFunction` argument. Instead of implementing this option, I chose to ignore it in the above solution (it does work in the `contourDensityPlot` solution below).

Here is another example:

```
contourRegionPlot[Sin[x^2 + y^2]/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ContourStyle -> Black, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: Old style graphics]

If you leave out the styling, you'll get the version-8 default styles.

**Alternative image-based approach**

I don't know if my solution (based on *rasterization*, not your proposal) is saner, but it offers some additional possibilities. In case you haven't already tried it, you may want to look at my answer [on stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717608/how-to-decrease-file-size-of-exported-plots-while-keeping-labels-sharp/8723264#8723264). The post links to a page whose [parent page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/rasterDensityPlots.html) has several different functions that all use rasterized images for the shading. In this case, the relevant one would be `rasterContourPlot`. Since it uses images, one can apply opacity or potentially other image effects to the output.

But as I said, your approach of stacking different image levels seems very sane to me.

**Edit**

Among the rasterized solutions I list above, the first one I did was the one listed below. My rationale for it was: if I am going to try and fix the shading problem for `ContourPlot`, why not add a feature that I was looking for anyway:

While contour lines are good, I also like to have the color fill to have a *smooth* gradient representing the function more faithfully. With the uniform `ContourShading` of `ContourPlot`, it seems to me that you're sometimes losing too much information about the function. Of course if I *just* want smooth color gradients, I could use `DensityPlot` instead. But wanted *both*, gradients and contours. That's originally why I decided it was time to write my own replacement for `ContourPlot`, listed here:

```
contourDensityPlot[f_, rx_, ry_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 (* Created by Jens U.Nöckel for Mathematica 8,revised 12/2011*)
 Module[{img, cont, p, plotRangeRule, densityOptions, contourOptions, 
   frameOptions, rangeCoords}, 
  densityOptions = 
   Join[FilterRules[{opts}, 
     FilterRules[Options[DensityPlot], 
      Except[{Prolog, Epilog, FrameTicks, PlotLabel, ImagePadding, 
        GridLines, Mesh, AspectRatio, PlotRangePadding, Frame, 
        Axes}]]], {PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None, 
     Frame -> None, Axes -> None}];
  p = DensityPlot[f, rx, ry, Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, densityOptions]];
  plotRangeRule = FilterRules[Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[p], PlotRange];
  contourOptions = 
   Join[FilterRules[{opts}, 
     FilterRules[Options[ContourPlot], 
      Except[{Prolog, Epilog, FrameTicks, Background, ContourShading, 
        Frame, Axes}]]], {Frame -> None, Axes -> None, 
     ContourShading -> False}];
  (* //The density plot img and contour plot cont are created here:*)
  img = Rasterize[p];
  cont = If[
    MemberQ[{0, 
      None}, (Contours /. FilterRules[{opts}, Contours])], {}, 
    ContourPlot[f, rx, ry, 
     Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, contourOptions]]];
  (* //Before showing the plots,
  set the PlotRange for the frame which will be drawn separately:*)
  frameOptions = 
   Join[FilterRules[{opts}, 
     FilterRules[Options[Graphics], 
      Except[{PlotRangeClipping, PlotRange}]]], {plotRangeRule, 
     Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> True}];
  rangeCoords = Transpose[PlotRange /. plotRangeRule];
  (* //To align the image img with the contour plot,enclose img in a//
  bounding box rectangle of the same dimensions as cont,
  //and then combine with cont using Show:*)
  Show[Graphics[{Inset[
      Show[SetAlphaChannel[img, 
        "ShadingOpacity" /. {opts} /. {"ShadingOpacity" -> 1}], 
       AspectRatio -> Full], rangeCoords[[1]], {0, 0}, 
      rangeCoords[[2]] - rangeCoords[[1]]]}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> None], cont, 
   Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, frameOptions]]]
```

With your example, it produces the following output. To get this result, using the rasterized image of the `DensityPlot` was the only "sane" alternative.

```
contourDensityPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: contourDensityPlot]

I should add a note about the **options**: you can feed this function with the options for `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot`.  You can completely suppress the ContourPlot output by giving the option `Contours -> None`.

I also added an option `"ShadingOpacity"` that can be used to make the shaded background transparent. The shading is fully opaque for `"ShadingOpacity" -> 1` and fully transparent for `"ShadingOpacity" -> 0`. This option is useful if you want to combine the plot with a Prolog, or if you have added Gridlines -> Automatic which usually will be hidden behind the density plot shading.

**Edit 2**
As mentioned in the comment to the question, I also tried `polygone` (a command-line tool you have to run in Terminal), and got mixed results with EPS exported from Mathematica version 8.

Comment: Actually density + contours is possible like this too: `DensityPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {Range[-2, 2, .5]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`  The quality will not be as good.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem of the grid lines in PDF export on Mac OS X that started our odyssey...

Comment: It's really easy to extract the polygon sets that form the different regions in the contour plot (they're grouped in `GraphicsGroup`s).  I wonder how difficult it would be to write a program that finds the outer cover of polygons.  With `RegionPlot` everything was easy because the outline was generated as well.  With `ContourPlot` it's not easy to convert the contours to an outline of a region.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK, I added my attempts based on a RegionPlot approach. Using the contour lines from ContourPlot directly didn't work out for me, unfortunately.

Comment: It's slower but it's gives much (much!) nicer PFD files (both in terms of size, display speed and rendering quality)! On average, PD file size is reduced by a factor of 10 in my own contour plots. I'd **+100** that if I weren't a new user…

Comment: @F'x Thanks - there are still some tiny wrinkles: e.g., the shaded areas have "contour line borders" where they intersect the plotrange rectangle. But I hope that will be acceptable to most people, especially considering the hugely reduced file size (smaller even than the rasterized plots in typical cases).

Comment: @Jens This is so useful, thank you! Just a remark: `GridLines` are not shown because `Inset`s seem to be drawn on top. I solved this for myself by putting the `Inset` as the `Prolog` in the final `Show`.

Answer (score 24):

### Merging polygons in `ContourPlot`

A seven-hour train ride and a coach with an electric outlet gave me an opportunity to implement a `ContourPlot` fixer.  This method heavily relies on the precise structure of the output that `ContourPlot` produces.  It relies on version 8 features, and I won't be surprised if it break in future versions.  But it works pretty well now.

Features of the `cleanContourPlot` function given at the end of this post:

- It will merge polygons shaded with the same colour into a single `FilledCurve`.  This will speed up rendering in Mathematica, and will prevent the polygon edge artefacts when exporting to vector formats
- The function will preserve all features of the contour plot, including several options that control styling, clipping, labels, `Epilog`, etc.

The idea is that `ContourPlot` puts each solid-filled region in a `GraphicsGroup`.  This makes it easy to extract the polygons belonging to one region.  Then we can convert the multiple-polygon region into a `FilledCurve`, in a similar way to how it's done in the `RegionPlot` question.

The styled groups are extracted into the `groups` variable.  The point coordinates from the `GraphicsGroup` are in `points`.  It is essential that when a single point belongs to multiple regions with the same shading, `ContourPlot` still generates two separate instances of this point.  The contour lines are extracted into `lines`.

The polygon merger algorithm works like this:

1. Find all polygon edges (`edges`)
2. Those edges that belong to a single polygon only are on the outside of the region, and will be part of the cover polygon (`cover`)
3. After extracting the cover edges, they must be ordered sequentially.  This is done by interpreting them as the edges of a graph and finding an Eulerian cycle in all connected components of the graph ([thanks Vitaliy!](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3237/12))

Step 3. might fail in certain uncommon cases.  If there is a point in the cover which is part of not only 2, but 4 edges (such as the point in the middle of a filled shape that looks like `8`), there will be more than one Eulerian cycle.  There is no guarantee that `FindEulerianCycles` will find the right one.  These cases do occur occasionally, for example in `ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`.  If we were using `FindHamiltonianCycle` instead of `FindEulerianCycle`, the function would fail.  Since we use `FindEulerianCycle`, it does give a result, but in this case the result is correct by mere chance.  If anyone encounters a case where part of a shaded region gets removed due to this, it can be fixed by slightly changing the domain of the plot.

All in all, function works remarkably well in practice, even on complex examples.  I tried about half of the examples in the docs, and it worked on all of them, preserving all options.  Here's one example:

```
{min, {steps}} = 
  Reap[NMinimize[{(x - 1)^2 + 100 (y - x^2)^2, 
     x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {{x, -1, -1/2}, {y, -1, -1/2}}, 
    StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}], Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]];

cp = ContourPlot[(x - 1)^2 + 100 (y - x^2)^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Contours -> 
   Function[{lo, hi}, Exp[Range[0.01, Log[hi], (Log[hi] - 0.01)/10]]],
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Epilog -> {Green, Line[steps], Red, Point[steps]}]

cleanContourPlot[cp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might notice that `Polygon`s are not anti-aliased by default in this plot while the `FilledCurve` is.  This may make the (by default semi-transparent) contour lines look a little strange on dark backgrounds, when rendered in Mathematica.  It's very fine when exported to a PDF though.

Should the anti-aliasing bother anyone, it is easily turned off by wrapping the `FilledCurve` in `Style[..., Antialiasing -> False]`.  This'll give an output identical to the original `ContourPlot` down to the pixel, except faster to render.

---

Here's the code of the function.  Enjoy!

```
cleanContourPlot[cp_Graphics] :=
 Module[{points, groups, regions, lines},
  groups = 
   Cases[cp, {style__, g_GraphicsGroup} :> {{style}, g}, Infinity];
  points = 
   First@Cases[cp, GraphicsComplex[pts_, ___] :> pts, Infinity];
  regions = Table[
    Module[{group, style, polys, edges, cover, graph},
     {style, group} = g;
     polys = Join @@ Cases[group, Polygon[pt_, ___] :> pt, Infinity];
     edges = Join @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ polys);
     cover = Cases[Tally[Sort /@ edges], {e_, 1} :> e];
     graph = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ cover];
     {Sequence @@ style, 
      FilledCurve[
       List /@ Line /@ First /@ 
          Map[First, 
           FindEulerianCycle /@ (Subgraph[graph, #] &) /@ 
             ConnectedComponents[graph], {3}]]}
     ],
    {g, groups}];
  lines = Cases[cp, _Tooltip, Infinity];
  Graphics[GraphicsComplex[points, {regions, lines}], 
   Sequence @@ Options[cp]]
  ]

cleanContourPlot[Legended[cp_Graphics, rest___]] :=
    Legended[cleanContourPlot[cp], rest]
```

### Rasterizing the background

Another approach to solving the same problem would be rasterizing the background of the plot while keeping axes, frames, labels, epilogs as vector objects.  I've used the function given at the end to rasterize some huge density plots (with up to 30,000 polygons).  The function preserves plot coordinates, so it's easy to position annotations or other objects on top.  It's also possible to re-use the density plot in composite figures (e.g. those made with `LevelScheme`).

```
rasterizeBackground[g_, res_: 450] :=
 Show[
   Rasterize[
    Show[g,
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, 
      LabelStyle -> Opacity[0], FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[0], 
      FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], AxesStyle -> Opacity[0], 
      TicksStyle -> Opacity[0], PlotRangeClipping -> False
    ], 
    "Graphics",
    ImageResolution -> res] /. 
   Raster[data_, rect_, rest__] :> 
    Raster[data, 
     Transpose@OptionValue[AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange], PlotRange], 
    rest], Sequence @@ Options[g], Sequence @@ Options[g, PlotRange]]
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer (and code)! It gets the original 836 kB PDF file to a 239 kB one, so it's still heavier than the RegionPlot-based approach but probably closer to the original ContourPlot (because it's derived from it) and thus more failure-resistant.

Comment: @F'x I think the size also depends on how details the (adaptive) sampling ends up being.  With `MaxRecursion -> 0` the file should be smaller and of worse quality.  I'm sure `RegionPlot` and `ContourPlot` will differ in how many sampling points they use.  Sorry about posting this in a rush, I wrote it on the train while I was offline.  I'll read it through again tomorrow.  Good night!

Comment: Is it possible to generalize this to other mathematica graphics. 3D graphics like a sphere or a pyramid with shading show similar edge artifacts in the PDF.

Comment: @Szabolcs cleanContourPlot seems to work very well, even on ListContourPlot. With the RegionPlot approach of this question, one could also write a cleanContourPlot function, but now there isn't much motivation for that. Next time you could take the bus, then all our plot problems will be fixed.

Comment: As a v7 user I cannot test this but +1 for effort if nothing else!

Comment: This works absolutely splendidly, preserving all the features of ContourPlot while solving its one major shortcoming. Well done.

Comment: @Szabolcs This is excellent, but it somehow seems to sometimes *increase* the footprint of the image. For `plot=ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 Contours -> 20]`, running `ByteCount[plot, cleanContourPlot[plot]` returns roughly `{2.3MB, 5MB}`. I find this completely befuddling - you've removed a bunch of points and the information on how to connect them, so the footprint should decrease. Maybe the data structure is less efficient? Any thoughts on why this should be the case?

Comment: Ah, the notorious Rosenbrock function!

Answer (score 11):

So I've changed your function around a little bit, but I've also added some of the functionality you're after. I think you are looking for:

- [`OptionsPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html)
- [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html)
- [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Options.html)
- [Tutorial on creating functions with options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html)

Also, while checking if there were new questions, I noticed this intro to some of the above functions: [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options)

Here is the new function:

```
Clear[graph]
graph[expr_, level_, contours_, color_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{p, pOpt, allLines},
  allLines = Flatten@Reverse@Table[
      p = RegionPlot[
        expr < level, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> None, 
        Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[RegionPlot]]]
        ];
      pOpt = p[[2]];
      {EdgeForm@Directive[Black, Thickness[Medium]], 
       FaceForm@Directive[Opacity[1], color], 
       FilledCurve[List /@ Cases[Normal[p], _Line, Infinity]]}
      , contours];
  Graphics[allLines, pOpt, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]]
  ]
```

If I use it as follows:

```
graph[Cos[x] + 1.1*Sin[y], c, {c, -2.2, 2.2, 0.2}, Hue[(c + 2)/4], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, Automatic}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

I get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you get a bit of the functionality back. This can probably act as a jumping off point.

Comment: oops, thanks @R.M. for fixing things up!

Comment: Although I upvoted this, I see a problem with the approach proposed by F'x (thinking out loud here, maybe solutions are possible): it will be hard to figure out how to emulate Contours->Automatic unless you first do an entire ContourPlot and then re-do the table of RegionPlots. That would make things even more inefficient.

Comment: @Jens yes, although I tend to think once you're stepping away from ContourPlot into rolling your own, things become harder to do nicely. I was just trying to show how to extend the function with OptionsPattern[].

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option using `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` and `MeshRegion` to automatically compute the bounding graphics primitives for the `GraphicsComplex`:

```
Clear[mergeGGroups, mergeGGroup];
mergeGGroup[pts_, GraphicsGroup[p : {__Polygon}], 
  ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Show@
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   MeshRegion[pts, p, AspectRatio -> 1],
   ops,
   AspectRatio -> 1
   ]
mergeGGroups[g_GraphicsComplex, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

  Module[{pts = g[[1]]},
   Quiet@ReplaceAll[g,
     {EdgeForm[], c_RGBColor, gp_GraphicsGroup} :>
      ReplacePart[
       mergeGGroup[pts, gp, ops][[1]], 
       {2, 1} -> Directive[EdgeForm[], c]
       ]
     ]
   ];
cleanContourPlot[p_] :=
 ReplacePart[p,
  1 -> mergeGGroups[p[[1]]]
  ]
```

I get this for a simple test:

```
test = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}];
newPlot = cleanContourPlot@test; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.160781, Null}
```

And we can see it looks the same;

```
CloudDeploy[ExportForm[newPlot, "PDF"], "contour_test.pdf", 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/contour_test.pdf

```
CloudDeploy[ExportForm[test, "PDF"], "contour_test_original.pdf", 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/contour_test_original.pdf

But the former is ~5x smaller for me. In some preliminary tests it also manages to avoid the meshing issues seen before, so that's a definite win, too.

Comment: +1 for this approach, but I'm getting errors like `"The cell Polygon[{11357,2534,14117}] is degenerate."` in version 10.1.  Any comment on that before I try to dig into it myself?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps) @Jens posted the solution to your problem: (defining a rule once)

```
contourPlotRule=({EdgeForm[], r_?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor, GrayLevel}, 
                                          Head[#]] &), i___} :> {EdgeForm[r], r, i});
YOURIMAGE /. contourPlotRule
```

Comment: The [solution you quote](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps) was already linked from my post: while it reduces the aliasing issues, it does not change PDF file size, which is the main point of my question…