# Simple algorithm to find cycles in edge list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, algorithm, sorting

I have the edge list of an undirected graph which consists of disjoint "cycles" only.   Example:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 5}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Each vertex has exactly two edges connecting to it.  Each cycle has at least three vertices.  The vertices are denoted by integers $1..n$.  The edge list is given in some random order.  The edges appear in random orientations (i.e. `{1,2}` might be given as `{2,1}`)

I need to break the graph into cycles and sort the vertices in the order they're connected.  For example, if the input is:

```
{{7, 6}, {5, 6}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {2, 1}, {7, 5}}
```

then I want the output

```
{ {1, 2, 3, 4},
  {5, 6, 7} }
```

The first sublist corresponds to the tetragon, the second one corresponds to the triangle.  The vertices must appear in the order they're connected.

Performance requirements: the maximum vertex count is a few thousand---it should run near-instantaneously for an input of this size.  An $n \log n$ solution is possible.  However, I'm more interested in a concise and elegant solution than a performant one using e.g. `Compile`.

Note: while it was easiest to state the problem in terms of graphs, it's not really a graph theoretical problem, so don't feel compelled to use `Graph` unless it's really advantageous.

---

**Clarification:**  This question is not (only) about finding connected components.  It is  about ordering vertices along the cycles.  Actually my practical problem is that I have the *edges* of a polygon in random order and orientation, and I need to sort them so I can use them in `Polygon` and related primitives.

A sample dataset can be downloaded using `Import["http://w504215.open.ge.tt/1/files/3XgvcEF/0/blob?download", "WDX"]`.

Comment: The `Import` link is unfortunately now broken. Since this has a good answer it could be removed? BTW thanks for [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3279/1000) :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited to account for @Szabolcs comment**

A index-disordered edge list (a bit different from yours):

```
el = {{3, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {5, 8}, {4, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 4}, {8, 1}}
```

Let's visualize with labels

```
gr = Graph[el, VertexLabels -> "Name", PlotRangePadding -> .2]
```

[image]

This will pick up the cycles but reorder them (as @Szabolcs reflects in the comment)

```
In[1]:= ConnectedComponents[gr]

Out[1]= {{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {4, 6, 7}}
```

We see this ordering is wrong because there is no edge between vertices 1 and 2. This more elaborate line will work:

```
In[2]:= Map[First, (FindHamiltonianCycle /@ (Subgraph[gr, #] & /@ 
         ConnectedComponents[gr])), {3}]

Out[2]= {{{1, 3, 2, 5, 8}}, {{4, 6, 7}}}
```

`FindEulerianCycle` would work too.

I wonder how it scales if you check this on your ~1000 vertex case.

Comment: I am well aware of this function, but the main task is ordering vertices according to the connections, not merely finding connected components.  `{1,2,3,4}` is a good output because the connections are `1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-1`, but `{2,1,4,3}` is not.  There's no guarantee `ConnectedComponents` won't return the latter.

Comment: @Szabolcs I understand the problem now - edited. I'm curious how will this compare against non-graphs methods.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  Again, you are assuming that the edges/vertices will be correctly ordered.  I uploaded a sample dataset (see update to the question).  The method you describe gives a list starting with `{1024, 1028, ...}`, yet vertices `1024` and `1028` are not connected.  In the returned sublist any two consecutive vertices must be connected, as well as the last and first vertex of the sublist.

Comment: @Szabolcs I realized that - replacing `EdgeList` with `FindHamiltonianCycle` fixes it. I will take a look at your data set too.

Comment: Alright, now it's time for a *+1*. :-) Thank you!

Comment: [This is what I needed it for](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3279/12), in case you are curious :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs did you find another way to solve this?

Comment: No, your way works fine, I just forgot to accept the answer ... `FindEulerianCycle` seems to be a bit faster.  I had a way, but it turned out to give incorrect results in some cases.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps [ExtractCycles](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/ExtractCycles.html) (in the *Combinatorica* package) does what you require?

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
ExtractCycles@FromUnorderedPairs@el
```

gives

> (*  {{7, 4, 6, 7}, {8, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8}} *)

Your sample dataset produces 4 cycles:

```
ExtractCycles@FromUnorderedPairs@data
```

the first of which is the following:

> (* {522, 518, 521, 527, 532, 535, 541, 550, 558, 563, 567, 578, 589,
>   593, 603, 608, 611, 615, 627, 638, 649, 659, 668, 674, 681, 689, 700,
>   712, 715, 720, 725, 734, 743, 750, 755, 771, 786, 793, 801, 812,
>   823, 829, 834, 837, 850, 861, 869, 877, 881, 890, 899, 906, 917,
>   929, 932, 935, 941, 949, 955, 966, 977, 981, 985, 995, 1005, 1009,
>   1013, 1018, 1021, 1025, 1029, 1032, 1030, 1026, 1022, 1016, 1014,
>   1010, 1006, 1002, 986, 982, 978, 974, 956, 952, 942, 937, 934, 930,
>   926, 903, 900, 896, 882, 878, 874, 862, 858, 839, 835, 832, 824,
>   820, 802, 798, 785, 782, 758, 744, 740, 726, 716, 711, 708, 690,
>   686, 671, 669, 666, 650, 640, 636, 616, 612, 607, 604, 594, 590,
>   586, 568, 564, 560, 542, 538, 536, 530, 528, 524, 522} *)