# Computing the equivalence classes of the symmetric transitive closure of a relation

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs, for example:

```
pairs={{13, 10}, {12, 14}, {10, 36}, {35, 11}, {3, 5}, {1, 6},
{20, 24}, {21, 22}, {33, 7}, {31, 8}, {31, 27}, {32, 25}, 
{21, 35}, {34, 19}, {18, 15}, {14, 16}, {9, 5}, {4, 7}, 
{1, 13}, {15, 2}, {6, 36}, {4, 34}, {8, 2}, {9, 3}, {25, 20},
{19, 26}, {22, 11}, {23, 12}, {32, 28}, {30, 33}, {23, 16},
{24, 17}, {29, 27}, {26, 30}, {17, 28}, {18, 29}};
```

`pairs` can be seen as the definition of a relation $R$. $x$ and $y$ satisfy the relation if and only if `{x,y}` $\in$ `pairs`. I need to compute the equivalence classes of the symmetric transitive closure of $R$.

In other words, I need to compute a list `eqvclss`. The elements of `eqvclss` are lists themselves. For example, 13, 10, 36, 6, 1, ... should all be in the same list in `eqvclss`. (If you understand that, then I explained the question properly; if you don't, say so in the comments so I can try to improve).

Comment: Related:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3234/121

Comment: From `{13,10}` and `{10, 36}`, you conclude that `10` and `13` belong together. But `13` also belongs with `1` because `{1, 13}` exists. However, there is no pair `{1, 10}` or `{10, 1}`, so `1` shouldn't be in the same group as `10`, which is in the same group as  `13` which belongs with `1`. So the problem for `Gather` is that your identity relation is not transitive. As a result, you have to give up some conditions. Maybe you want all gathered groups to be numbers that are at least _indirectly_ connected?

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your comment. I see now. I did some drastic edits to the question (prior to seeing your comment). Now it's more to the point of what I want. Your comment now seems out of context, but it does answer the original question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### ConnectedComponents

Using [Daniel Lichtblau's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6184/125) to a [related  question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6183/125)

```
ConnectedComponents[pairs] //Sort /@ # & //Sort (* thanks: CarlWoll *)
```

> {{3, 5, 9},
>        {11, 21, 22, 35},
>        {12, 14, 16, 23},
>        {1, 6, 10, 13, 36},
>        {17, 20, 24, 25, 28, 32},
>        {2, 8, 15, 18, 27, 29, 31},
>        {4, 7, 19, 26, 30, 33, 34}}

In versions prior to  10.3 use

```
 ConnectedComponents[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ pairs]] //Sort /@ # & //Sort
```

### MatrixPower

Implementing transitive closure using `MatrixPower`:

```
m = Max@pairs;

(*the adjacency matrix of atomic elements in pairs:*)
SparseArray[pairs ~Append~ {i_, i_} -> 1, {m, m}];

(*symmetrize the adjacency matrix:*)
% + %\[Transpose] // Sign;

(*find the transitive closure:*)
Sign @ MatrixPower[N@%, m];

(*eliminate duplicate rows,and extract the atomic elements of pairs in each row:*)
Select[DeleteDuplicates @ Normal @ %, Tr@# > 1 &];
Join @@ Position[#, 1] & /@ %;

(*organize:*)
Sort[Sort /@ %]
```

> {{3, 5, 9},
>         {11, 21, 22, 35},
>         {12, 14, 16, 23},
>         {1, 6, 10, 13, 36},
>         {17, 20, 24, 25, 28, 32},
>         {2, 8, 15, 18, 27, 29, 31},
>         {4, 7, 19, 26, 30, 33, 34}}

Comment: +1 I think like this better than my answer.

Comment: @becko, thanks for the vote. (Does the edit answer your request re horizontal scrollbar?)

Comment: Yes. The annoying scrollbar is gone. Thanks.

Comment: Slightly simpler is `ConnectedComponents[pairs]`

Comment: Thank you @Carl. Updated with the simpler version.

Answer (score 6):

Adapting [Heike's fine answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6185/121) from the prior question:

```
pairs //. x_ :> Union @@@ Gather[x, # ⋂ #2 =!= {} &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 6, 10, 13, 36},
>  {12, 14, 16, 23},
>  {11, 21, 22, 35},
>  {3, 5,  9},
>  {17, 20, 24, 25, 28, 32},
>  {4, 7, 19, 26, 30, 33, 34},
>  {2, 8, 15, 18, 27, 29, 31}}
> ```

Comment: I had not seen that. I can see is almost the same to what I did.

Comment: @becko and I did not see your answer before posting this, nevertheless I think it is different enough to be of interest.  Do you agree?

Comment: Yes. Besides, your way is more elegantly coded.

Answer (score 5):

Here's code for version 7:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

gr = FromUnorderedPairs @ pairs;

ConnectedComponents @ gr
```

> ```
> {{1, 6, 10, 13, 36},
>  {2, 8, 15, 18, 27, 29, 31},
>  {3, 5, 9},
>  {4, 7, 19, 26, 30, 33, 34},
>  {11, 21, 22, 35},
>  {12, 14, 16, 23},
>  {17, 20, 24, 25, 28, 32}}
> ```

```
GraphPlot[gr, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

I have separately posted this method as an answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/simple-algorithm-to-find-cycles-in-edge-list)

If you want to preserve the order in which the vertices are connected within each cycle,

[ExtractCycles](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/ExtractCycles.html) (in the *Combinatorica* package) may also be of interest.

For example

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
ExtractCycles@FromUnorderedPairs@pairs
```

gives

> (* {
>   {28, 17, 24, 20, 25, 32, 28},
>
> {23, 12, 14, 16, 23},
>
> {35, 11, 22, 21, 35},
>
> {34, 4, 7, 33, 30, 26, 19, 34},
>
> {9, 3, 5, 9},
>
> {15, 2, 8, 31, 27, 29, 18, 15},
>
> {13, 1, 6, 36, 10, 13}
>   } *)

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to do it:

```
SymmetricTransitiveClosure[pairs : {{_, _} ..}] := 
    FixedPoint[DeleteDuplicates /@ 
        Flatten /@ Gather[#, Intersection[#1, #2] =!= {} &] &, pairs]
```

I won't acccept this yet. Perhaps someone comes up with something better.