# Combining lists with common elements efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computing the equivalence classes of the symmetric transitive closure of a relation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7620/computing-the-equivalence-classes-of-the-symmetric-transitive-closure-of-a-relat)

I am required to process sets consisting of 2-element subsets of integers by combining those subsets whose intersection is nonempty.

For example, given

`X = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {7, 4}, {2, 5}}`

my routine `merge` will output

`merge[X] = {{3, 4, 7}, {1, 2, 5}}` .

As all `List` elements are considered as sets, duplicate entries and list order are to be ignored.

In fact I have implemented such an algorithm in Mathematica, however I suspect it is horribly inefficient and am looking for any reasonable way to improve its performance.

My implementation uses FixedPoint and is broken into two parts :

```
merge0[x_] := Block[{x0 = x},
Do[
If[i != j && Intersection[x[[i]], x[[j]]] != {}, 
x0 = Join[Delete[x, {{i}, {j}}], {Union@Flatten[Join[x[[i]], x[[j]]]]}];
Break[]], 
{i, Length[x]}, {j, i}]; x0]

merge[x_] := FixedPoint[merge0, x]
```

Thanks and regards,

Daniel

Comment: What is the expected result of `{{a,b},{b,c},{c,d}}`? Seems your fuction returns `{a,b,c,d}` ... so the "intersection" is some kind of "transitive" property here

Comment: Would `Union @@@ FindClusters[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {7, 4}, {2, 5}}, DistanceFunction -> Composition[Abs, NeedlemanWunschSimilarity]]` suit your needs?

Comment: I intend to close this as a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7620/121 -- anyone disagree?

Answer (score 4):

I remember helping someone else with a similar problem recently in chat. Anyway, here's a solution using `//.` or `ReplaceRepeated`. If your lists are very large, then you should look into alternative solutions, because the performance of `//.` along with `___` will degrade quickly. Otherwise, it's a fine solution and I'd use it if I had a similar problem.

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {7, 4}, {2, 5}}; (* your list *)
list //. {h___, a_List, m___, b_List, t___} :> {h, m, Union[a, b], t} /; 
    Intersection[a, b] =!= {}
(* {{3, 4, 7}, {1, 2, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pairs = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {7, 4}, {2, 5}, {5, 8}};

relativesF=ConnectedComponents[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@ # & /@ #]]&
relativesF@pairs
(* {{1, 2, 5, 8}, {3, 4, 7}} *)
```

or

```
relativesF2 = DeleteDuplicates/@ Flatten/@ Gather[#, (Intersection[#1, #2] !={} &)] &;
FixedPoint[relativesF2 , pairs]
(* {{1, 2, 5, 8}, {3, 4, 7}} *)
```

or

```
Nest[relativesF2, pairs, Length[pairs]]
(* {{1, 2, 5, 8}, {3, 4, 7}} *)
```

Comment: kguler, since you are here: do you disagree with my intention to close this question? (see comment above)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, not at all. Actually, just noticed your comment as I was trying to put together the links to other related questions to post a similar comment.