# Gather lists according to another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a first list of pairs like this one:

```
list1= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {13, 14}, {15, 16}, {17, 18}, {19, 20}, {21, 22}, {23, 24}, {25, 26}, {27, 28}, {29, 30}, {31, 32}, {33, 34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}, {39, 40}, {41, 42}, {43, 44}, {45, 46}, {47, 48}, {49, 50}}
```

And a second one containing information about how the elements of the first list are related:

```
list2 = {{1, 46}, {5, 27}, {8, 42}, {21, 26, 29}, {31, 45}, {33, 36}, {35, 37}, {47, 49}}
```

How can I gather elements of the first list using list2 as a reference to get groups like these:

```
{{{1, 2}, {45, 46}, {31, 32}}, {{5, 6}, {27, 28}}, {{7, 8}, {41, 42}}, {{21, 22}, {25, 26}, {29, 30}}, {{31, 32}, {45, 46}}, {{33, 34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}}, {{47, 48}, {49, 50}}}
```

So what it's happening here is that, element `{1, 46}` of list2 is telling that the pair containing element "1" (`{1, 2}`) of list1 is linked to element containing element "46" (`{45, 46}`) and so on.

Note that when you use list 2 element `{35, 37}` to gather `{{35, 36}, {37, 38}}` you should consider that list 2 element `{33, 36}` already linked `{{33, 34}, {35, 36}}` so you will have a three element group `{{33, 34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}}`.

I tried to use graph related functions but couldn't make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,

```
dp = Dispatch@Flatten[{#1 -> {##}, #2 -> {##}} & @@@ list1]

list2 = Sequence @@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ list2

ConnectedComponents@Graph@Union[Sort /@ UndirectedEdge @@@ (list2 /. dp)]

(* ==>

{{{31, 32}, {45, 46}, {1, 2}}, {{21, 22}, {25, 26}, {29, 30}}, {{37, 
   38}, {35, 36}, {33, 34}}, {{41, 42}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {27, 
   28}}, {{49, 50}, {47, 48}}}

 *)
```

Comment: This is not the same output you quote.  Please check if there's a mistake in the output you posted or whether I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yep, that's totally what I meant. My output is wrong, I'll fix it.

Comment: @xtian777x Don't be too quick to accept!  My code was wrong ;-)  I didn't notice the 3-element list in `list2`.  It's fixed now.  But it's not pretty.  You might consider waiting for a prettier solution :)

Comment: Yeah I was coming here to post the error I got. Thanx a lot, that'll work for now. My solution was not even close to be pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a direct list-manipulation approach using a variation of Heike's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6185/5) for combining subsets with similar terms:

```
Cases[list1, {___, Alternatives @@ #, ___}, 2] & /@ list2 //. 
    x_ :> Union @@@ Gather[x, Intersection@## =!= {} &]

(* {{{1, 2}, {31, 32}, {45, 46}}, {{5, 6}, {27, 28}}, {{7, 8}, {41, 42}}, 
    {{21, 22}, {25, 26}, {29, 30}}, {{33, 34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}}, {{47, 48}, {49, 50}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c = Cases[list1, {x_,  y_} /; (MatchQ[x, Alternatives @@ #] || 
                               MatchQ[y, Alternatives @@ #]) :> {x, y}] & /@ list2

c //. {x___, {a___, y__, b___}, p___, {c___, y__, d___},  z___} :> {x, {a, y, b, c, d}, p, z}

(*
 {{{1, 2}, {45, 46}, {31, 32}}, 
  {{5, 6}, {27, 28}}, 
  {{7, 8}, {41, 42}}, 
  {{21, 22}, {25, 26}, {29, 30}}, 
  {{33, 34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}}, 
  {{47, 48}, {49, 50}}}
*)
```

Comment: Noooooooo! I considered this, but... `ReplaceRepeated` + multiple `BlankNullSequence` == kaboom! :D

Comment: @rm-rf Yep, You preferred copy-pasting Heike's answer. I know

Comment: The joke's still on you buddy, since you copy-pasted [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11060/5) =) I'll have a Tantō ready for you.

Comment: @rm-rf I'm sure I've an older one of mine to cite with the same bad trick

Comment: @belisarius Are we having a battle of whose old notebook has the worst code? Bring it on!

Comment: @rm-rf This one is older: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5143575/353410. Your turn

Comment: Ok, I give up. You have a Ph.D. in bad code.

Comment: @rm-rf I'll require advice from my lawyers. I'm not quite sure if one can sue a frog for calumnies

Comment: Too bad, you have only [one possible candidate](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/28/Philip_Fry.png) to be your lawyer... good luck!