# Finding elementary cycles of (directed) graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm, combinatorics, group-theory

I need to enumerate all the simple cycles (i.e. elementary cycles where no vertex is repeated other than the starting) of a graph which has both directed and undirected edges, where we can treat the undirected edges as doubly directed. (Specifically, I am looking at the Cayley graphs of S3 and S4, which can be produced using `CayleyGraph[SymmetricGroup[3]]` and `CayleyGraph[SymmetricGroup[4]]` respectively.)

I have tried two ways of doing this so far. First, I have tried using `ExtractCycles` in the *Combinatorica* package, as detailed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7632/5) by TomD. For example, entering the ordered pairs for S3 (as "el"):

```
el = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {4, 6}, {5, 4}, {5, 2}, 
{6, 5}, {6, 3}}
```

And then using:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
ExtractCycles@FromOrderedPairs@el
```

returns:

```
{{5, 4, 6, 5}, {6, 3, 6}, {5, 2, 5}, {4, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 3}}
```

However, that set is incomplete - what about e.g. `{{5, 4, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5}}`? These are simple cycles, so why are they not included in the list? The output for S4 is also much truncated (obviously we would expect a *lot* of cycles there, but the output gives only eighteen).

The second thing I tried was [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2722/5) by kguler. Taking the example of S3, using `CycleGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True]` gave the right results, but `CycleGraph[4, DirectedEdges -> True]` did not - i.e. the cycles `{5, 4, 1, 2, 5}` etc. were not picked up again. Presumably this is something to do with the doubly directed edges?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

**Edit:** As requested, the ordered pairs for the Cayley graph of S4 are:

```
el2 = {{1, 2}, {1, 9}, {2, 3}, {2, 17}, {3, 4}, {3, 13}, {4, 1}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}, {5, 6},
{6, 16}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {7, 22}, {8, 5}, {8, 10}, {9, 1}, {9, 10}, {10, 8}, {10, 11},
{11, 12}, {11, 21}, {12, 9}, {12, 18}, {13, 14}, {13, 3}, {14, 15}, {14, 20}, {15, 16},
{15, 23}, {16, 13}, {16, 6}, {17, 2}, {17, 18}, {18, 19}, {18, 12}, {19, 24}, {19, 20},
{20, 17}, {20, 14}, {21, 11}, {21, 22}, {22, 7}, {22, 23}, {23, 15}, {23, 24}, {24, 19},
{24, 21}}
```

Comment: I've added the ordered pairs for the Cayley graph of S3, as well as the code to produce the Cayley graphs. Is this what's needed?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  If you don't mind including the S4 data too that would be helpful for version 7 users like me, who don't have `CayleyGraph`.

Comment: Sure. Just added them at the bottom.

Comment: Would you tell me if Daniel's method is giving the right output?  It does not agree with the output from mine.

Comment: I think his method gives the right output, but there is some redundancy (for example, `{1,4,1}` and `{4,1,4}` are both included for the graph of S3).

Comment: Mr. Wizard (& Jimeree) The updated/corrected version [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9836/combinatorica-girth-and-findcycle-disagreement) should be both correct and irredundant. Let me know if you have time to check and find it to be otherwise.

Comment: I've generalized a bit the question in light of my answer, I hope I did not interfere with any policy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a brute force method:

```
cycles[el_] :=
 Module[{f, edges = Rule @@@ el // Dispatch},
  f[x_, b___, x_] := {{x, b, x}};
  f[___, x_, ___, x_] = {};
  f[c___, v_] := Join @@ (f[c, v, #] & /@ ReplaceList[v, edges]);
  Join @@ f /@ Union @@ el
 ]
```

In the code above the line `f[___, x_, ___, x_] = {};` was used for clarity, but [faster duplicate tests exist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6745/121).  For short cycles `f[c__] /; ! UnsameQ@c = {};` should be fast(est), but if long cycles may be present you should use `f[c__] /; Signature@{c} === 0 = {};` or `f[c__] /; {c} =!= DeleteDuplicates@{c} = {};`

Test:

```
el = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {4, 6},
      {5, 4}, {5, 2}, {6, 5}, {6, 3}};

cycles[el]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1}, {1, 2, 5, 4, 1}, {1, 2, 5, 4, 6,
>    3, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1,
>    2}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 2}, {2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 6, 5, 
>   2}, {2, 5, 4, 1, 2}, {2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 2, 
>   3}, {3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 6, 
>   3}, {3, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 6, 5, 2, 3}, {3, 6, 3}, {4, 1, 2, 3, 
>   6, 5, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 5, 4}, {4, 1, 4}, {4, 6, 5, 4}, {4, 6, 5, 2, 3, 
>   1, 4}, {4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4}, {4, 6, 3, 1, 4}, {5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 
>   5}, {5, 4, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 4, 6, 5}, {5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 2, 3, 
>   1, 4, 6, 5}, {5, 2, 3, 6, 5}, {5, 2, 5}, {6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6}, {6, 
>   5, 4, 6}, {6, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6}, {6, 5, 2, 3, 6}, {6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4,
>    6}, {6, 3, 1, 4, 6}, {6, 3, 6}}
> ```

To remove the duplicate cycles from this output one can use:

```
DeleteDuplicates[RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#, 1] - 1] & /@ Most /@ #]&
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3}, {1, 4},
>  {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 6, 3}, {2, 3, 6, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 6, 5}}
> ```

Here is an alternative approach to remove the duplicates on-the-fly with a form of memoization.  It seems it may be more or less efficient depending on the graph; I have not tested it well yet.

```
cycles2[el_] :=
 Module[{f, edges = Rule @@@ el // Dispatch},
  f[x_, b___, x_] := (
    (f[##] = {}) & @@@ NestList[RotateLeft, {x, b}, Length@{x, b} - 1];
    {{x, b}}
   );
  f[c__] /; Signature@{c} === 0 = {};
  f[c___, v_] := Join @@ (f[c, v, #] & /@ ReplaceList[v, edges]);
  Join @@ f /@ Union @@ el
  ]

cycles2[el]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3}, {1, 4},
>  {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 6, 3}, {2, 3, 6, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 6, 5}}
> ```

Comment: That's great, thanks! I have two questions though:
1) That list is complete, but it now gives multiple entries for the same cycle, in that it gives all the possible cyclic permutations of each cycle. For example, {1,2,3,2} and {3,1,2,3} are both included, but they are, in fact, the same cycle. Is there any way of only including one entry for each cycle?
2) Out of interest, what is the complexity of this algorithm? How long would you expect it to take to compute all the cycles for S4?
Anyway, thanks very much - that's really useful!

Comment: Oh, I just tried it for S4 and it seemed to be very quick. Great!

Comment: @Jimeree **(1)** Glad I can help; I got lucky as I wasn't sure this was what you needed. **(2)** Don't be too quick to Accept an answer, as it may discourage someone from posting a better one.  **(3)** `{1,2,3,2}` should not be included and I do not see it in my output, nevertheless I shall think about that.  **(4)** I have no idea what the computational complexity of this method is (yet) but off hand I would expect it to be pretty good with short cycles and struggle on really long ones.

Comment: Sorry, I meant {1,2,3,1}. That and {3,1,2,3} are the same cycle up to cyclic reordering.

Comment: @Jimeree how large are the graphs you are working with?  It should be practical to remove that kind of duplicate at the end of the calculation, but I'm struggling to *use* that duplication to make the calculation more efficient (though it should be possible).

Comment: Ideally I'd like to push up to graphs with hundreds of vertices, but I'm not sure how realistic that is. I'd be very happy if there were a way to have only one entry per cycle-up-to-cyclic-reordering for graphs of a size similar to S3 and S4.

Comment: @Jimeree please confirm that this gives the output you want (`long` is the output of the function above): `DeleteDuplicates[RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#, 1] - 1] &@Most@# & /@ long]`. (This leaves off the duplicated vertex in each cycle but it could be re-added as needed.)

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jimeree I updated my answer to include the developments in these comments and to provide an additional method.  I still suspect a more intelligent approach exists but this will have to do for now.

Answer (score 8):

Below is an implementation of **Johnson's 1975 exhaustive algorithm** (see [PDF](http://dutta.csc.ncsu.edu/csc791_spring07/wrap/circuits_johnson.pdf), AFAIK the fastest exhaustive algorithm), improved upon the rather procedural version of Daniel Skates (see [*Mathematica* demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EnumeratingCyclesOfADirectedGraph/)). A hand-crafted C-version of the code is also available (if you mail me), which adds a further tenfold increase of speed compared to the *Mathematica* version. **Code is at end of post (`findAllCycles`).**

Note:

- the input should be either a graph or a binary adjacency matrix (`SparseArray` is ok);
- self-loops are allowed (Johnson's algorithm is unable to correctly find all, so they are assessed beforehand and the diagonal of the adjacency matrix is zeroed for the algorithm);
- multiple edges (other than doubly directed ones) or wheights are not allowed.

Result comparison:

```
el = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 6},
      {4, 1}, {4, 6}, {5, 4}, {5, 2}, {6, 5}, {6, 3}};
g = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ el, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

```
mrW = DeleteDuplicates[RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#, 1] - 1] &@Most@# & /@ (cycles@el)];
z = findAllCycles@g

Sort@mrW === Sort@z
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3}, {1, 4},
>  {1, 4, 6, 3}, {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 6, 5}, {2, 5}, {4, 6, 5}, {3, 6}}
>
> True
> ```

Time comparison, by generating 1000 weakly connected directed graphs (since MrWizard's method is redundant, Johnson's method is expected to be faster):

```
iteration = 1000;
nodeRange = {9, 12};
edgeProb = .3;
adjList = elList = {};
While[
  n = RandomInteger@nodeRange;
  adj = RandomChoice[{1-edgeProb, edgeProb} -> {0, 1}, {n, n}];
  (* only weakly conncected graphs should be checked *)
  Length@adjList < iteration && ConnectedGraphQ@AdjacencyGraph[adj, DirectedEdges -> False],
  (* create adjacency matrix and edge list separately for the two functions *)
  AppendTo[adjList, adj];
  AppendTo[elList, Position[Normal@adj, 1, {2}]];
  ];

AbsoluteTiming[
 mrW = (DeleteDuplicates[RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#, 1] - 1] &@
          Most@# & /@ (cycles@#)]) & /@ elList;]
AbsoluteTiming[z = findAllCycles /@ adjList;]
```

> ```
> {23.590349, Null}   (* MrW *)
> {3.780216, Null}    (* Z *)
> ```

Note that `cycles` and `findAllCycles` return results in different orders, so I omitted the direct comparison and only the number of found cycles are checked:

```
Length /@ mrW === Length /@ z
```

> True

Code:

```
(* wrappers for Graph and SparseArray input *)
findAllCycles[g_Graph] := Module[{nodes = VertexList@g},
   Replace[findAllCycles@Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@g, 
    Thread[Range@Length@nodes -> nodes], {2}]
   ];
findAllCycles[s_SparseArray] := findAllCycles@Normal@s;

(* Johnson's algorithm *)
findAllCycles[a_?MatrixQ] := 
  Module[{unblock, circuit, n = Length@a, adj, loops, AK, s = 1, 
    stack = {}, circuitsFound = {}, B, blocked},

   (* remove self-loops, as Johnson's algorithm is unable to deal with them. *)
   loops = Position[Diagonal@a, 1];
   adj = a*(1 - IdentityMatrix@n);

   B = Table[{}, {n}];
   blocked = Table[False, {n}];

   unblock[u_Integer] := Module[{w},
     blocked[[u]] = False;
     While[Length@B[[u]] > 0,
      w = B[[u, 1]];
      B[[u]] = Drop[B[[u]], 1];
      If[blocked[[w]], unblock@w]];
     ];

   circuit[v_Integer] := Module[{f = False},
     stack = Append[stack, v];
     blocked[[v]] = True;
     Do[
      If[w == s,
       circuitsFound = Append[circuitsFound, stack]; f = True,
       If[! blocked[[w]] && circuit@w, f = True]
       ], {w, AK[[v]]}];
     If[f,
      unblock@v
      ,
      Do[If[FreeQ[B[[w]], v], B[[w]] = Join[B[[w]], {v}]], {w, AK[[v]]}];
      ];
     stack = Drop[stack, -1];
     f
     ];

   While[s < n,
    AK = Take[adj, {s, n}, {s, n}];
    AK = Flatten@Position[#, 1] & /@ AK;
    AK = AK /. {x_ :> (x + s - 1)};
    AK = Join[Table[{}, {s - 1}], AK];
    If[AK === {},
     s = n,
     Do[blocked[[i]] = False; B[[i]] = {}, {i, s, n}];
     circuit@s;
     s = s + 1;
     ]
    ];
   Join[loops, circuitsFound]
   ];
```

Answer (score 4):

Mostly I cribbed this from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/cycles-of-length-n-in-a-graph). I simply changed the line that converts input to the particular sparse representation used by the main part of the code.

Important caveat: I do not know for a fact that this code is correct for the directed case.

```
extendCycle[cyc_List, edges_List] := 
 Map[If[# > First[cyc] && ! MemberQ[cyc, #], Append[cyc, #], 
    Null /. Null :> Sequence[]] &, edges[[Last[cyc]]]]

cycles[mat_, k_] := Module[{n = Length[mat], m2, cyc, cyclist},
  m2 = Map[Last, Split[Sort[mat], First[#1] == First[#2] &], {2}] ;
  cyclist = 
   Flatten[Drop[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, m2, {2}], -k + 1], 1];
  Do[cyclist = 
    Flatten[Map[extendCycle[#, m2] &, cyclist], 1], {k - 2}];
  Map[If[MemberQ[m2[[Last[#]]], First[#]], Append[#, First[#]], 
     Null /. Null :> Sequence[]] &, cyclist]]
```

Your simpler example:

```
el = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {4, 
    6}, {5, 4}, {5, 2}, {6, 5}, {6, 3}};

Timing[
 Table[cycles[el, j], {j, 2, Length[Union[Flatten[el]]]}] /. {} :> 
   Sequence[]]

(* Out[436]= {0., {{{1, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 2}, {3, 6, 3}, {4, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 
    5}}, {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 5, 4}}, {{1, 2, 5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 3, 
    1}, {2, 3, 6, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 4, 6, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1}, {1,
     2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3, 1}}}} *)
```

Your bigger case:

```
el2 = {{1, 2}, {1, 9}, {2, 3}, {2, 17}, {3, 4}, {3, 13}, {4, 1}, {4, 
    5}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {6, 16}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {7, 22}, {8, 5}, {8, 
    10}, {9, 1}, {9, 10}, {10, 8}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {11, 21}, {12, 
    9}, {12, 18}, {13, 14}, {13, 3}, {14, 15}, {14, 20}, {15, 
    16}, {15, 23}, {16, 13}, {16, 6}, {17, 2}, {17, 18}, {18, 
    19}, {18, 12}, {19, 24}, {19, 20}, {20, 17}, {20, 14}, {21, 
    11}, {21, 22}, {22, 7}, {22, 23}, {23, 15}, {23, 24}, {24, 
    19}, {24, 21}};

Timing[
 cycs2 = Table[
     cycles[el2, j], {j, 2, Length[Union[Flatten[el2]]]}] /. {} :> 
     Sequence[];]

(* Out[439]= {0.340000, Null} *)
```

Now check sizes.

```
Length[cycs2]

(* Out[440]= 10 *)

Length[Flatten[cycs2, 1]]

(* Out[443]= 199 *)
```

Upshot: Not too bad in performance, if it happens to be correct.

Answer (score 4):

One approach, born out of curiosity more than anything, is to take the determinant, extract the permutations from the indices, and then cycle decompose. I don't think this is a very efficient method as `Det` is slow, but it seems to work.

To cycle decompose, I use `combinatoricatocycles[]` with Mathematica 7 (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PermutationCycles.html#935135757)), rather than the new Mathematica 8 function  [PermutationCycles](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PermutationCycles.html)

```
detPerms[ei_] := List @@@ (List @@ (Det@SparseArray[# -> 
            a[#] & /@ ei]) /. {-x_ -> x}) /. a[{x_, y_}] -> y
```

Applying to el:

```
Union@Flatten[combinatoricatocycles /@ #, 1] &@detPerms[el]
```

> (* {{4, 1}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {6, 5, 4}, {2, 5, 4, 1}, {3, 6,
>   5,    2}, {4, 6, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1}, {4, 6,
>   5,    2, 3, 1}}  *)

And to el2:

```
Length@Union@Flatten[combinatoricatocycles /@ #, 1] &@detPerms[el2]
```

> (* 180 *)

**combinatoricatocycles** (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PermutationCycles.html#935135757))

```
combinatoricatocycles[p_] := 
 Module[{k, j, first, np = p, q = Table[0, {Length[p]}], i}, 
  DeleteCases[
   Table[If[np[[i]] == 0, {}, j = 1; first = np[[i]]; np[[i]] = 0;
     k = q[[j++]] = first;
     While[np[[k]] != 0, q[[j++]] = np[[k]]; np[[k]] = 0;
      k = q[[j - 1]]];
     Take[q, j - 1]], {i, Length[p]}], _?(# === {} &)]]
```