# Combining nested lists that meet certain criteria for a permutation

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I have the following list representing a permutation on 26 characters:

```
{{G, G}, {O, P}, {V, L}, {Y, Y}, {C, X}, {H, I}, {P, S}, {W, R},
 {I, H}, {Q, D}, {X, C}, {J, B}, {D, M}, {K, O}, {R, N}, {Z, K},
 {L, Q}, {M, F}, {S, A}, {N, Z}, {A, T}, {E, U}, {T, W}, {B, V},
 {F, E}, {U, J}}
```

How can I "simplify" this list to show the cyclic form of the permutations? A possibility of the above list would be:

```
{{A, T, W, R, N, Z, K, O, P, S}, {B, V, L, Q, D, M, F, E, U, J},
 {C, X}, {G}, {H, I}, {Y}}
```

I'm new to *Mathematica* and I could write an ugly loop to do this, but I've noticed that *Mathematica* usually has elegant solutions for problems like this that I wouldn't be able to think of on my own. Thus, I haven't tried to do anything because I couldn't find anything while searching for this.

---

I could still be overlooking something, but I tried converting the list to numeral values with A=1 and I got the following error:

```
Cycles::reppoint: Cycles[{{7, 7}, {15, 16}, {22, 12},
  {25, 25}, {3, 24}, {8, 9}, {16, 19}, {23, 18}, {9, 8},
  {17, 4}, {24, 3}, {10, 2}, {4, 13}, {11, 15}, {18, 14},
  {26, 11}, {12, 17}, {13, 6}, {19, 1}, {14, 26}, {1, 20},
  {5, 21}, {20, 23}, {2, 22}, {6, 5}, {21, 10}}]
contains repeated integers.
```

Comment: Did you check `Cycles[]`?

Comment: Looking at it now -- I'm having trouble understanding what format it should be in, but it looks like that will work if I convert the characters into character codes?

Comment: Closely related to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/simple-algorithm-to-find-cycles-in-edge-list, although the code there seems to not like dealing with non-indexed vertices.

Comment: Such questions were pondered in [the Middle Ages](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2003/Jun/msg00314.html) and even [antiquity](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/May/msg00119.html). Remind's one of the infamous debates "How many permutations can dance on the head of a pin?" Or the adage "It is easier for a cycle to fit through the eye of a needle, than for a camel to get into heaven." Or words to that effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is: What cycles describe the permutation from `order1` to `order2`?

```
order1 = {"G", "O", "V", "Y", "C", "H", "P", "W", "I", "Q", "X", "J", "D", "K", "R", "Z", "L", "M", "S", "N", "A", "E", "T", "B", "F", "U"};
order2 = {"G", "P", "L", "Y", "X", "I", "S", "R", "H", "D", "C", "B", "M", "O", "N", "K", "Q", "F", "A", "Z", "T", "U", "W", "V", "E", "J"};
```

If that is indeed what you are asking, `FindPermutation` will give the cycles:

```
FindPermutation[order1, order2]
```

> Cycles[{{2, 14, 16, 20, 15, 8, 23, 21, 19, 7}, {3, 24, 12, 26, 22, 25,
>       18, 13, 10, 17}, {5, 11}, {6, 9}}]

---

**What the Cycles Represent**

The following diagram shows the first cycle walk: `{2, 14, 16, 20, 15, 8, 23, 21, 19, 7}`. Note that the cycle forms a closed loop (position 7 connects to position 2).

[image: cycle]

---

**Inferring the permutation from the cycles**

Suppose we knew the original ordering and the cycles but didn't know the second ordering:

```
Permute[order1, Cycles[{{2, 14, 16, 20, 15, 8, 23, 21, 19, 7}, {3, 24, 12, 26, 22, 
25, 18, 13, 10, 17}, {5, 11}, {6, 9}}]]
```

> {"G", "P", "L", "Y", "X", "I", "S", "R", "H", "D", "C", "B", "M", \
>   "O", "N", "K", "Q", "F", "A", "Z", "T", "U", "W", "V", "E", "J"}

```
% === order2
```

> True

Comment: That is great to know! So `datas[[All, 
     1]][[#]] & /@ (Cycles[{{2, 14, 16, 20, 15, 8, 23, 21, 19, 7}, {3,24, 12, 26, 22, 25, 18, 13, 10, 17}, {5, 11}, {6, 9}}][[1, All]])` (for example) will give how I interpreted the question (without the singletons).

Comment: Interesting. I see how the code produces your connected components but I'm still trying to understand your underlying thinking. Looks like you treated the ordered pairs as arrows. Actually, this is something like the arrows I drew in the explanation above! Yes, very interesting.

Comment: After quite a bit of confusion, I'm going to settle on this. Nicely answered and explained, David.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because, as [highphi](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2174/highphi) pointed out in a comment, `StrongComponents` does not do what is asked, (the order of the vertices are not the same as given by `GraphPlot`) and I consider the answer misleading. `Extract Cycles` might be worth considering (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7633/106)) Needs["Combinatorica`"]
`Characters /@FromCharacterCode /@ 
  ExtractCycles@FromOrderedPairs[Flatten /@ ToCharacterCode /@ datas]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler example that illustrates the steps and built-in functions that can be used:

```
transpositionlist = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {3, 7}, {6, 8}, {6, 10}, {4, 4}, {9, 9}}
(* First delete elements corresponding to points fixed `{i,i}` *)
DeleteCases[transpositionlist, {x_, x_}];
(* Then make a cycle out  of each element. Combined with the previous step: *)
Cycles /@ List /@ DeleteCases[transpositionlist, {x_, x_}]
(* {Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 5}}], Cycles[{{3, 7}}],  Cycles[{{6, 8}}], Cycles[{{6, 10}}]}*)
(* Take the `PermutationProduct` of these cycles. Again, with all steps combined:*)
PermutationProduct @@ (Cycles /@  List /@ DeleteCases[transpositionlist, {x_, x_}])
 (* Cycles[{{1, 2, 5}, {3, 7}, {6, 8, 10}}]*)
```

If needed,

```
PermutationList[Cycles[{{1, 2, 5}, {3, 7}, {6, 8, 10}}]]
```

gives the permutation of the original list:

```
(* {5, 1, 7, 4, 2, 10, 3, 6, 9, 8} *)
```

Update: A modifed version of your list

```
trlist1={{g, g}, {p, p}, {v, l}, {y, y}, {c, x}, {h, i}, {p, s}, 
 {w, r}, {i, h}, {q, d}, {x, c}, {j, b}, {d, m}, {k, o}, {r,n}, {z, k}, 
 {l, q}, {m, f}, {s, a}, {n, z}, {a, t}, {e, u}, {t, w}, {b, v}, {f, e}, {u, j}};
```

In order to use `Cycles` we need to convert the letters to integers. `ArrayComponents` is a convenient bulit-in that can be used for this purpose:

```
trlist2= ArrayComponents[trlist1]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}, {2, 10}, {11, 12}, {9, 8},
  {13, 14}, {7, 6}, {15, 16}, {14, 17}, {18, 19}, {12, 20}, {21, 18},
  {4, 13}, {17, 22}, {10, 23}, {20, 21}, {23, 24}, {25, 26},
  {24, 11}, {16, 3}, {22, 25}, {26, 15}}*)
```

Then,

```
PermutationProduct @@ (Cycles /@   List /@ DeleteCases[trlist2, {x_, x_}])
(* Cycles[{{2, 11, 21, 18, 19, 20, 12, 24, 23, 10}, {3, 13, 25, 15},
     {4, 16, 26, 22, 17, 14}}]*)
```

And, using this permutation to permute `CharacterRange["a", "z"]`

```
Permute[CharacterRange["a", "z"], %]
```

we get

```
(* {"a", "j", "o", "n", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "w", "b", "t",
     "c", "q", "y", "d", "v", "u", "r", "s", "k", "z", "x", "l", "m", "p"} *)
```

Comment: @highphi, my pleasure. Welcome to Mma.SE.

Comment: @highphi, based on David's new and correct answer, you should consider your accept. My post is based on mis-interpreting the pairs in your list to stand for length-two cycles (whose product is the original 'unknown' permutation).