# How to get better quality EPS graphics

Tags: image-processing, eps-format

Yesterday, I was doing any Tables of 15 graphs similar to the next example, to save .eps and use in latex.

In the generation of the graphs Mathematica spends many time. Is possible to reduce this time, and work for the cpu?

I found that Mathematica save .eps with a big  (not necessary) size. between 4 and 5 MB. When it´s obvious that for this image 400 or 500 KB is enough.

So... how to obtain eps from MAthematica with a reasonable size (10-20% of the size that I have commented)

In this example

```
ContourPlot[peaks[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", ContourLines -> False, 
 Contours -> 25, LabelStyle -> {Bold, 20}, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize -> .036, Point[ {{1, 2}, {1.5, 2.5}}], 
   Cyan, PointSize -> .036, Point[ {{-1, 2}, {-1.5, 2.5}}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

Yesterday I resolve the problem, saving jpg/png and converting to .eps to can use in latex, because I put 12 or 15 images per page, and don´t need a high quality, but I would like any solutions to this issue.

Comment: I'd just do as you did. save to png and then use convert to eps (level 3, to get best compression). I do not know of option in M do that. I myself save to png then convert outside.

Comment: you could use `export[fname_, im_,opts___] := Export[fname, Rasterize[im,ImageResolution->300],opts]`

Comment: Once again I ask you to take the time to format your code properly. And that includes not dumping it into the editor as one long line that requires readers to do a lot of scrolling,

Comment: @m_goldberg, ok. Curiously I was formating to appear so, without using multiple lines to only a Command. I edited. Thank you for your advice, m_goldberg. I´m agree with you.

Comment: @chris could you explain  any more the proccess you propose. I think that it be interesting but I can´t understand well the parameters, and how to use. I tried , but get errors and what is the possible options?

Comment: [Related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185030/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-eps-file)

Comment: @Pickett Yes, precisely the Ian Thompson´s comment has induce me to start this issue in the MathematicaSE

Comment: fyi, the convert command using level3 eps is this `convert file.png eps3:file.eps`  notice no space between `eps3:` and `file.eps`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the [`FixPolygons` package by Will Robertson](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7029/). It merges adjacent polygons with the same color producing vector image of lesser size with the same (or ever better) quality.

For installing the package you should copy the `FixPolygons.m` file to the "Mathematica/Applications" directory in your user profile. Then you can use it as follows:

```
<< FixPolygons`
g2 = g // FixPolygons
Export["test.eps", g2]
```

In the case the above does not fit your needs but you wish to produce high-quality output you can try to use the "rasters in vectors" approach described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1550/280) (originally proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6301676/590388)) for 3D graphics (but the same method will work for 2D graphics). The idea it to rasterize only the largest and problematic part of the vector image - the contour plot itself, keeping axes and labels in vector form. This will dramatically reduce the size of the exported EPS file while allowing you to get any resolution you need.

You can also try Jens Nöckel's "rasters in vectors" functions [published](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/rasterDensityPlots.html) on his homepage (see also his answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/280)).

Comment: @alexy-popkov I have tested your propose, but the result is equela 4.5 MB for that image.

Comment: @Mika I have added description of another approach.

Comment: Yes, I refer to the initial ( FixPolygons ) proposal. The other link I´ll try later, still not be tested. Thank you.