# How to export images in EPS format that can be opened in CorelDraw

Tags: graphics, export, interoperability, eps-format

I am preparing a paper. The journal requirements are odd: only eps files for pictures are accepted. All pictures I have drawn in *Mathematica* and exported in eps format in the usual way: `Export[path, "filename.eps", mmaImageName]`, where `mmaImageName`is the name I give to the image in question within *Mathematica*.

Now in order to check what have I obtained by such an export, I need to open this eps file and have a look. Out of all graphic applications understanding eps, I only have CorelDraw X3 in which I am not at all a specialist. All I want to use CorelDraw for is to have a look. This is what I see when I open my eps file in the CorelDraw:

[image]

In other words, I see nothing and, hence, I am not sure that I can send these eps files to the journal.

There is a work-around. It is to export the image as, say, pdf (or something else), import it into Corel and then export it from Corel as eps.

My question: Is there any trick that would enable me to export the eps file directly from *Mathematica* in a way that I can open it directly in CorelDraw?

Comment: You might want to install [Ghostview or GSView](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) to examine eps files.

Comment: You should use Linux, then all what you have to do is click on the file ;)  but I would not even save from Mathematica as eps. You could save the image to pdf, and then crop it then convert it to eps, like this: `pdfcrop --margins 10 --clip image.pdf image.pdf` then `pdftops -f 1 -l 1  -level3 -eps image.pdf` pdfcrop comes with texlive. Very nice program. It removes all empty space around the image from the pdf. I have script that does the above for all my pdf images.

Comment: @Nasser  Unfortunateloy, I do not use Lunix

Comment: I tried opening a _Mathematica_ generated EPS file with Adobe Reader on OS X. Abode Reader didn't like it at all -- said was corrupt. If Adobe Reader can't open an EPS file, I think one must conclude the file is bad. So it appears to me that _Mathematica_'s EPS generator is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CorelDRAW is not a PostScript viewer. Its ability to import EPS files has serious limitations and is not guaranteed to preserve the original appearance of the figure. One workaround is to *place* the EPS file inside of the CorelDRAW document instead of importing it but it has a drawback: you will see only EPS preview, not the actual content of the EPS file. (**Note that you should `Export` into `"EPS"` from *Mathematica* with option `"PreviewFormat"` set to anything but `None`: by default it is set to `None` and preview is not generated.**)

For this in CorelDraw you should create a new document (`File` ► `New...`), then place your EPS file via `File` ► `Import...` ► (select your file in the "Import" dialog) ► press `Import` button ► in the "Import EPS" dialog check "**Place as encapsulated PostScript**" ► press `OK`. Then you should click inside of the document at any place where you wish to place your EPS file.

Here is how this dialog looks in CorelDRAW X6:

[image: screenshot]

I personally prefer to import EPS file in MS Word which ([starting from MS Office 2003](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/439881)) creates its own preview from the PostScript code of the EPS file, and does not use the preview image embedded into the EPS file (which may be absent). In the [linked](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/439881) Adobe Community thread and in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/650524/71768) limitations of the MS Office EPS Import filter are discussed.

Another possibility is to `Import` the EPS file backward into *Mathematica* (but it does not always preserve the original appearance of the figure).

The simplest solution of course would be to have something like Adobe Acrobat, GhostScript or [free EPS/PS Viewer](http://epsviewer.org) installed.

Comment: Thank you. The PreviewFormat story I missed.

Comment: Alexey, could you give me a hint on a decreasing the size of the eps file obtained as discussed. I am submitting a paper to arXive with Mma-produced images. arXive limits the size of the possible upload and requires images to only be eps, if the paper file is tex. I must, therefore, decrease the size of the eps image files, produced as discussed above (including your answer).  I understand that this is not a right place to discuss a CorelDraw question, but might you kindly reply to my private mail boulbitch@gmx.de not to violate rules?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I don't think that CorelDRAW is the right tool to decrease the size of EPS file. In the most cases you can achieve this by some sort of simplification of the underlying structure of the figure and this can be best achieved on the *Mathematica* side (there are already [several questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=eps+file+size) on this topic, see in particular [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50893/280)).

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch What you probably can achieve with third-party tools (and what *Mathematica* still cannot do) is to compress the data streams inside of the EPS file and delete unnecessary information. I never tried to do this but [here](http://www.academia.edu/7189775/How_to_compress_the_size_of_EPS_image_file) you can find one approach.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch There is a [paper dedicated to compression of PDF files](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96szabo.pdf). All these methods are in principle applicable to EPS because PDF and EPS can be converted to each other and *basically* are written on the same PostScript language.

Answer (score 3):

I think your syntax is wrong. Try the following

```
Export[pathWithFileName, mmaImageName, "EPS"],
```

where pathWithFileName contains the path and the name of the exported file i.e. "path/filename.eps". In my answer the option "EPS" is not necessarily needed.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it is my miswritings, in fact I do exactly this, without the option "EPS" though