# Can Listplot output data to an image whilst leaving axes and labels as vectors?

Tags: plotting

**Question:**
Can Listplot be set to render the data as an image whilst leaving axes and labels as vectors when saved as a PDF?

**Context:**
I have around 100,000 points in my listplot which when saved to a PDF is a huge 14 MB, for just one small figure in my LaTex file. I could easily save it as a PNG but then the axes and labels don't look nice especially if you zoom in.

Update: Alternatively could the detail of the vector PDF output be reduced?

Comment: to have nice pictures you should use Export command and set proper imagesize, e.g.: Export["qwerty.png", obj, ImageSize -> 1500]. You may also need to tweak the size of the fonts for labels and grid for better result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's true I can make them high res. I guess I want the axes and labels to be vectors as it seems more professional.

Comment: Use .eps instead of .pdf, which is more usual for latex and generates files of much lower size. Also you can consider using fewer points - say 1000 or less instead of 100000

Comment: This the original was a good question (+1), and my guess is that the answer could go in the line of using `Rasterize` on a `Plot` without `Axes` and then superimpose a plot with `Axes` but no data.

Comment: The linked question deals with 3D graphics, but I think halirutan's solution should adapt easily to ListPlot

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3279/280) (see Section "Rasterizing the background").