# Rasterized density plot with vector axes

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get the plot below exported in a small PDF file?

The plot below is made in the following steps:

1. Create a `StreamPlot`
2. Create a `DensityPlot`, where the `DensityPlot` has to have a lot of sampling points in some cases !!
3. Put the two of them together.

[image: VortexAntivortex]

Now whenever I save this as a PDF-file it becomes huge due to the large amount of sampling points.

Now I was wondering if it was possible to get this in a single (small !!) PDF-file? As far as I understand I need to rasterize the density plot and put the axes separately. Now I've seen some answers regarding this for a `ListDensityPlot`, but it doesn't seem to work for a `DensityPlot`. Whenever I try to put the `PlotRangePadding` to `0` weird things happen. Next to that I've also not been able to put the legend next to the plot after rasterization. Are there any hints on this ?

Code to reproduce the above example:

```
vx[x_, y_, d_] := -y*(1/((x - d)^2 + y^2) - 1/((x - 1/d)^2 + y^2)) + 
  y*(1/((x + d)^2 + y^2) - 1/((x + 1/d)^2 + y^2))

vy[x_, y_,d_] := (x - d)/((x - d)^2 + y^2) - (x - 1/d)/((x - 1/d)^2 + 
   y^2) - (x + d)/((x + d)^2 + y^2) + (x + 1/d)/((x + 1/d)^2 + y^2)

v[x_, y_, d_] := Sqrt[( 4 d^2 (-1 + d^2)^2 ((1 + x^2)^2 + 2 (-1 + x^2) y^2 + 
    y^4))/(((d - x)^2 + y^2) ((d + x)^2 + y^2) ((-1 + d x)^2 + 
    d^2 y^2) ((1 + d x)^2 + d^2 y^2))]

part1 = 
 StreamPlot[{vx[x, y, 0.6], vy[x, y, 0.6]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1.4, 
   1.4}, ImageSize -> 650, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  FrameStyle -> Black, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 22, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", StreamStyle -> "PinDart", 
  StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamScale -> .15, 
  AspectRatio -> ((1.4 - (-1.4))/(2 - (-2)))]

legend = 
 BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 15}}, LegendFunction -> "Panel", 
  LegendLabel -> 
   "|\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)|/(\[Kappa]/2\
\[Pi]R)", LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 14], 
  LegendMargins -> 0, LegendMarkerSize -> 400]

part2 = DensityPlot[{v[x, y, 0.6]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1.4, 1.4}, 
  ImageSize -> 650, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 22, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  AspectRatio -> ((1.4 - (-1.4))/(2 - (-2))), 
  FrameLabel -> {"x/R", "y/R"}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["The vortex-antivortex velocity field", Black, 30] , 
  PlotRange -> {0, 15}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  Epilog -> Style[Circle[{0, 0}, 1], {Thick, Dashed, White}], 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Right]]

plot = Show[part2, part1]
```

Comment: Related: [Jens's `contourDensityPlot` with vector contours and raster density](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/484).

Comment: @Rahul, that's for contourplots, there my problem disappears with the fixpolygons. This is not the case for a density plot

Comment: What are "fixpolygons"? Perhaps you missed the second part of the answer I linked to, which explicitly deals with a smooth density plot.

Comment: Great question, have you found an answer in newer versions? I have the same problem

Comment: @AimForClarity No, I actually just export the figure (without axes) as a (high quality) rastered figure and put a set of axes on top using TikZ.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Exporting graphics to PDF - huge file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1542/280)."

Comment: [`rasterizeBackground`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153557/280) can be a solution.

Comment: @AimForClarity Please see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `rasterizeBackground` function originally [written](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3279/280) by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) and then [improved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153557/280) by [Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang) requires further minor update and improvement in order to get it working for your case in recent versions of *Mathematica*.

Here is a substantially more reliable version of that function which doesn't depend on the [buggy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18034/280) `AbsoluteOptions` (I use here the workaround suggested by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/280) answer):

```
ClearAll[rasterizeBackground]
Options[rasterizeBackground] = {"TransparentBackground" -> False, Antialiasing -> False};
rasterizeBackground[g_Graphics, rs_Integer: 3000, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{raster, plotrange, rect}, {raster, plotrange} = 
   Reap[First@Rasterize[
      Show[g, Epilog -> {}, Prolog -> {}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, 
       ImageMargins -> 0, PlotLabel -> None, FrameTicks -> None, Frame -> None, 
       Axes -> None, Ticks -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
       Antialiasing -> OptionValue[Antialiasing], 
       GridLines -> {Function[Sow[{##}, "X"]; None], Function[Sow[{##}, "Y"]; None]}], 
      "Graphics", ImageSize -> rs, 
      Background -> 
       Replace[OptionValue["TransparentBackground"], {True -> None, False -> Automatic}]],
    _, #1 -> #2[[1]] &];
  rect = Transpose[{"X", "Y"} /. plotrange];
  Graphics[raster /. Raster[data_, _, rest__] :> Raster[data, rect, rest], Options[g]]]

rasterizeBackground[g_, rs_Integer: 3000, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 g /. gr_Graphics :> rasterizeBackground[gr, rs]
```

With this version rasterization of your `DensityPlot` can be made as easy as follows:

```
plot = Show[rasterizeBackground[part2, 1000], part1]
```

> [image: output]

The size of exported PDF file is reasonable and easily controllable by setting the raster size of the embedded image via the second argument of `rasterizeBackground`:

```
Export["plot.pdf", plot] // FileByteCount
```

> ```
> 490504
> ```

---

Additional example of use:

- [Adding the option `ChartElementFunction -> "GlassBoxWhisker"` to `BoxWhiskerChart` increases file size enormously](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209000/280)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following lines to your code in order to decrease the pdf-file size.

```
plot = Rasterize[plot, RasterSize -> 1000, ImageSize -> 650,ImageResolution -> 1000];
Export["plot.pdf", plot];
```

This method give us a file of aproximatelly 200kB instead of the previous 11MB.
If you want an eps-file, is better to convert the pdf-file rather than export the eps extension.

Comment: that will indeed work if I wanted to rasterize the complete plot. But it won't keep my axes in a vector-format, that's where my problem is :(.