# How can we Rasterize only plots profile without frame or labels?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, image, labeling

Exporting very dense `DensityPlot` or `Plot3D` figures as vectors (pdf, eps)  become very huge in size.
for example, exporting this fig as pdf gives 85MB in size

```
plot2d = DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16}, 
  FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 17] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
  ImageSize -> 200, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

Is it possible to  `Rasterize` only the plot profile without frames or labels such that when exporting as pdf they are still in vector form (frame and labels)?

and can it be done also for `Plot3D` (As I know labels can not be in vector style in Plot3D but at least can we `Rasterize` plot profile and Axes with labels independently? so we can assign high `Rasterize` on labels and low for plot profile )

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16}, 
 AxesLabel -> (MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 17] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
 ImageSize -> 200, ColorFunction -> Hue, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, -1.3, 0.5}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

**update**

For `DensityPlot` the problem was solved in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71870/rasterized-density-plot-with-vector-axes) answer. Now, we are left with the case of `Plot3D`, is it possible to do a similar thing as in `DensityPlot`?

i.e. I want to export the output of `Plot3D` as a vector style (pdf/eps) where only axes are in vector style and plot profile is arbitrary `RasterSize` in the background.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate a bit on how is this question not a duplicate of [Rasterized density plot with vector axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71870/10397)

Comment: thanks, @rhermans, yes it perfectly does for `DensityPlot` but not for `Plot3D`.

Comment: I still get poor resolution of labels even with `RasterSize` -> 4000`.. it would be nice if one can `Rasterize` profile and axes with labels independently and then combine all

Comment: And how do you propose to combine the low-resolution plot with the high-resolution axis? I like your question, I think the main issue is to get the 2D projection of the axis and frame to overlap perfectly on the bitmap. Probably you could split the problems into parts. Given a `Plot3D`,  `ViewProjection` and `ViewPoint`, extract the `Line` and `Text` that constitute `Frame` and `Axis` Lines, project them into a 2D `Graphics` with the rasterised 
`Plot3D` bitmap as the background.

Comment: I was thinking about Legended to do that, I know not an elegent way to do it!

Comment: I don't run into your issue at all on my Mac `$Version` is "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 18, 2020)". `Export["plt.pdf",plot2d]//FileByteCount` and `Export["plt.pdf",plot3d]//FileByteCount` gives 363 427 and 239 700 respectively. I can confirm the 2D plot generates a 90MB PDF on my linux machine, but not the 3D one. Can you post your version details? Exporting to vector graphics is a notoriously buggy process with Mathematica.

Comment: @kglr, Hey man we miss you:-)

Comment: None of the two answers so far seem satisfactory to me. Probably a better approach would be to extract `PlotRange`,  `ViewPoint` and `BoxRatios` from the 3D plot and make the 3D Box by hand as a set of 3D lines. Then apply the transformations for the perspective considering `ViewPoint`. That would output a vector 2D set of lines that could be overlayed to the rasterized plot.

Comment: would be nice if you have time to show us how to do that

Answer (score 4):

For `Plot3D`, here is a try and hope experts can improve it,

first for the plot profile

```
Rast1 = Rasterize[
  Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   LabelStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> None, Axes -> False, 
   Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5}, 
   ImagePadding -> 30, ViewPoint -> {1, -1.3, 0.5}, PlotTheme -> None,
    Mesh -> None], RasterSize -> 800, Background -> None, 
  ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

and then for axes and labels

```
Rast2 = Rasterize[
  Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16},
    AxesLabel -> (MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 17] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5}, ImagePadding -> 30, 
   ViewPoint -> {1, -1.3, 0.5}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], 
  RasterSize -> 4000, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

finally, combine both

```
Overlay[{Rast2, Rast1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the advantage of this over doing a high resolution raster of the original plot?  I would haven wanted to see the axis as vector drawings.

Comment: For publication or presentations, I want labels, frames, and axes to be in high resolution or a vector style with an acceptable size of the file as in DensityPlot as in the answer you posted in the comment. Since can not get axis as vector style with Plot3D (as I know), then my idea was to highly raster labels, frames, and axes and moderate for the profile (which has the large weight in the file size due to colors ). If I raster the whole 3D plot the size will be large again.

Comment: Isn't the axis high-resolution picture already going to be large and heavy? You are not even restricting the number of colours of the axis raster. Probably you could show explicitly how the total file size turns out smaller at the end.

Comment: No, you can assign the same `RasterSize`  for the profile and axes and export it as pdf separately, the size of the profile will be much more larger.  e.g. for `RasterSize->4000` axes are 120KB and profile 1200KB, 10 times larger

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:

It appears the 3D case may be hopeless. After Mathematica 10.0 it appears 3D graphics is always rasterized when exporting to vector graphics and there's no good way around it. Full discussion here: [Export Plot3D in Mathematica 10.1 is Rasterized by default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87733/export-plot3d-in-mathematica-10-1-is-rasterized-by-default). They provide some workarounds in there, but none of them seem to work for me. It appears having a rasterized element will trigger the entire PDF to rasterize even in the proposed workarounds (e.g. using right-click, print graphic or insetting into a 2D `Graphics`). I believe this is simply a Mathematica limitation, which is a shame. If you have a way to revert to Mathematica 10.0 or before, my approach or another approach given in that answer, might work for you.

## Original Answer:

Here's a simple approach that gives vectorized axes and labels but a rasterized graph. Basically just make your graph without the axes or labels, `Rasterize` that, then add that image as an `Inset` in `Graphics` with the appropriate axes and labels. So for your 2d case (MaTeX was giving me problems so I omitted it):

```
graph = DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, ImageSize -> 200, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
   Frame -> False];
im = Rasterize[graph, Background -> None, ImageSize -> 400];
Graphics[Inset[im, {-4, -3}, {0, 0}, {8, 6}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, FontSize -> 17] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: 2d]

For the 3d case:

```
graph3D = 
  Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   ImageSize -> 200, ColorFunction -> Hue, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, 
   ViewPoint -> {1, -1.3, 0.5}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
   Background -> Opacity[0]];
im3d = Rasterize[graph3D, Background -> None, ImageSize -> 200];
Graphics3D[Inset[im3d], PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 1}}, 
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, Automatic}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16}, 
 Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, FontSize -> 17] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
 ImageSize -> 250, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, -1.3, 0.5}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: 3da]

If you want to keep all the options from `PlotTheme -> "Detailed"` you can make a "graph" with a trivial, transparent graph so you're just left with the axes, grids, and labels then `Show` that together with the `Rasterize`d image. I.e.

```
axes3D = Plot3D[0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 2, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, FontSize -> 17] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
   ImageSize -> 200, ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0] &), Mesh -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, 
   ViewPoint -> {1, -1.3, 0.5}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];
Show[axes3D, Graphics3D[Inset[im3d]], ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image: 3db]

There's a lot of playing around with these approaches you can do to get the styling you like. `Inset` can be a bit finicky when you resize things, but it shouldn't be hard to set the options in `Inset` and `Graphics` such that it looks like you want. Plus this has the advantage that you can explicitly control what gets rasterized and what stays vectorized.

Here's a super zoomed in version of the final PDF of the 2d plot. As you can see, the axes are indeed vectorized.

[image: zoom2d]

Comment: actually, your approach is similar to mine in the above answer. However, exporting as pdf my approach gives higher resolution with a smaller size than yours and of course with MaTex working fine.

Comment: and thank you for sharing your thoughts:-)

Comment: @valarmorghulis you can choose the options for resolution when you rasterize and/or export. However, my solution gives you vector graphics for your axes as you requested. I can confirm this on my Mac, I added it to the answer. If you don't see vectorized axes, what system and version of Mathematica are you using? Exporting to vector graphics is notoriously buggy in Mathematica and different versions and OS's may produce different results.

Comment: it gives a vector for `DensityPlot` (read my update of the question) but axes can't be in a vector when exporting `Plot3D`. Does the picture you posted for `Plot3D` or `DensityPlot`? my problem now is for `Plot3D` only.

Comment: @valarmorghulis I see, I can confirm my solution does rasterize the axes in 3D. This appears to be a known issue in Mathematica. I'm updating my answer to provide all the details about it.

Comment: @valarmorghulis updated!