# ContourPlot has extra mesh in PDF

Tags: plotting, mesh, pdf-format

When I create a contour plot it looks fine. When I copy as PDF, and paste into another document (e.g. Apple Mail, Keynote, etc.) it has an extra unwanted white mesh. This occurs even when the option Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True} is used.

Here is an example.

```
plot = ContourPlot[Exp[-Norm[{x, y}]^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}]
```

Here is the picture that results, after copying as PDF, pasting into Mail, and doing a screen grab.
[image: plot with mesh]

Here are the options:

```
Options[plot]


{DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, DisplayFunction :> Identity, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
     GridLinesStyle -> Directive[
    GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
     Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True, 
       "DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
     PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.02], 
        Scaled[0.02]}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}
```

I am using version 11.0.0.0 on Apple OS X 10.11.6 but the problem was present in previous versions.

I am aware that similar questions have been asked, but none provided a solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, if I right-click the graphic, select "Save graphic as...", and save as a PDF in Windows, then the PDF is clean, with no underlying mesh. This is true even without setting the `TransparentPolygonMesh` method explicitly. the output of my `Options` function is identical to yours.

Comment: I should have added: The resulting PDF looks clean in Adobe Acrobat. I just opened it in my GhostScript viewer, and it shows a somewhat uglier version of the mesh you show in your post. I then opened the PDF in PDF-XChange viewer, and that again gave a clean image, and so did Photoshop. My guess is what you are seeing is an artifact of your OS X PDF viewer.

Comment: Try the `cleanContourPlot` function from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3279/12).  It doesn't work on everything but it works well on your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saner alternative to ContourPlot fill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill)