# ContourPlot with BarLegend: vector format export problem

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format, mac-os-x

I have a couture plot which I want to export in vector format (e.g.PDF) and use in my latex. The example code from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html):

```
plot = ContourPlot[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> 8, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 150, 
     LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
     LegendLabel -> "Z"], {After, Top}], FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium],  AspectRatio -> Full]
```

It looks fine on Adobe products, but on macOS preview, gostscript and other LaTeX editors built-in PFD viewers it seems like this:

[image]

This is actually a very common problem and there are already many similar posts:

1. [ContourPlot has extra mesh in PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124174/contourplot-has-extra-mesh-in-pdf):
2. [Saner alternative to ContourPlot fill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill/3279#3279)
3. [Avoiding white lines inside filled area in RegionPlot exported as PDF or PS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps)
4. [Antialiasing option behaves weird (polygon edges visible in ContourPlot)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/381/antialiasing-option-behaves-weird-polygon-edges-visible-in-contourplot)
5. [ContourPlot has extra mesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94099/contourplot-has-extra-mesh)

I have tried all of them:

- From comments of [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124174/contourplot-has-extra-mesh-in-pdf) I tried adding `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}`
- From [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/381/antialiasing-option-behaves-weird-polygon-edges-visible-in-contourplot) I tried `Style[plot, Antialiasing -> False]`
- From [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps) I tried `/. {EdgeForm[], r_?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor, GrayLevel}, Head[#]] &), i___} :> {EdgeForm[r], r, i}` this lessens the issue but white lines are still there:

[image]

- Using `contourRegionPlot`function defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill/3279#3279) solves the issue, however it removes the `BarLegend` in the format I want!

I would appreciate if you could help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cleanContourPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3279/12) from one of the threads you linked.  It does not always work, but it can handle your example very well.

Without legends, a plot has the structure `Graphics[...]`. With legends, it has the structure `Legended[Graphics[...], ...]`.  Therefore `cleanContourPlot` must be used only on the first part of `Legended`.

---

```
Head[plot]
(* Legended *)

fixedPlot = MapAt[cleanContourPlot, plot, {1}]
```

[Avoid resizing figures with plots when exporting:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093783/695132)

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

This setting will keep its effect until you restart the front end.

```
Export["plot.pdf", fixedPlot]
```

Comment: I updated the `cleanContourPlot` function now so it would work automatically on `Legended`.

Comment: Novice here, would you mind ELI5?

Comment: It works like a charm. thanks a lot. you saved my day :)

Comment: @Foad I don't understand "ELI5"

Comment: Explain Like I'm Five :) Reddit lingo I think :)

Comment: @Foad There's a lot in there ... Which specific part do you not understand?

Comment: I could not understand it first, but then I just used it and it worked. you may ignore my comment.

Comment: I have one more issue, the `cleanContourPlot` function removes the `BoundaryStyle -> Black`

Comment: @Foad I do not have time to fix it now. I would use some quick and dirty workaround like `Epilog -> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-3, -2}, {3, 2}]}` where I took the rectangle dimensions from the ContourPlot variable bounds.

Comment: well actually my real plot is different and there I'm using a  `RegionFunction`

Comment: @Foad Can you plot the RegionFunction separately and superimpose?  E.g. if you have `x^2+y^2 < 5` then `ContourPlot[x^2+y^2 == 5, ...]` with black style and superimpose with `Show`.