# How can I save a density plot as a EPS file, but not a large file?

Tags: plotting, eps-format

How can I have a small size (.EPS) DensityPlot? In fact, I want to bring a lot of density plots in my paper and the teX file will be very heavy. What can I do?

Comment: DensityPlots are color gradient images. Exporting them into pure vector graphics typically either blows their size up or they look shabby. Maybe exporting a ContourPlot as vector graphic is more feasbile for you...

Comment: You must be one of the few people who are still using .eps file format for latex. Everyone has moved to PDF for images with latex long time ago.

Comment: @ Nasser : Actually, the journal forced the authors

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher: Would you kindly please guid me more clearly. Tanx

Comment: @Ak68 (I stumbled upon this just by chance because I was not pinged. There must be no whitespace between the @ and the user name.) If you already have a working Mathematica -> pdf pipeline for export, the simplest way to produce eps files would be to use external tools such as `pdf2eps` in the command line. Inscape is also an option. Actually, the last time I tried (several years ago, though), I found that the Mathematica eps export was rather buggy.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill -- See also some of the Q&A linked to it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was just about to cite that! For example, `g = contourRegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   Contours -> 20];` leads to a quite readable plot and exports to a 44kB file.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to replace the density plot with a [`Raster`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster.html).  The following makes a 28KB PDF file (sorry, my EPS exporter does not seem to work -- I always use PDF in TeX these days), which approximates `DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}]`.  The `DensityPlot[..]` took 1.8MB.

```
Legended[
 Graphics[
  Raster[
   Rescale@
    Table[Sin[x] Sin[y], {y, Subdivide[-3., 3., 100]}, {x, Subdivide[-4., 4., 100]}],
   ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient"
   ],
  FrameTicks -> {
    {Charting`ScaledTicks[{1/2 (100 + 33 #) &, -3 + 6 (# - 1/2)/99 &}],
     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{1/2 (100 + 33 #) &, -3 + 6 (# - 1/2)/99 &}]},
    {Charting`ScaledTicks[{1/8 (400 + 99 #) &, -4 + 8 (# - 1/2)/99 &}], 
     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{1/8 (400 + 99 #) &, -4 + 8 (# - 1/2)/99 &}]}},
  Frame -> True],
 BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-1., 1.}}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can adjust the raster size and [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) to suit.  If they all have the same dimensions and ranges, it might not be a headache.  Or one could try to write a general purpose function to do the above.  The functions in the ticks just map forward and back between the raster domain `{1, 100}` and the function domains, `{-4., 4.}` for `x` and `{-3., 3.}` for `y`.

Comment: @ Michael E2: No way! The pdf files are too heavy too :( 2 GB!!!!!! On the other hand, above plot do not have a good quality :/

Comment: @Ak68 You can improve the quality and predict the size, since the size is roughly proportional to n^2 for an n x n raster. But higher quality would seem to imply a larger size. You might be better off with DensityPlot, unless Henrik's suggestion of ContourPlot is acceptable. I have no idea what 2GB has to do with PDF. I don't get anywhere near that size.  That's a raster size of ~6000. To get better help, you need to provide an example.

Comment: @Ak68 That's what I meant. Better export the plot as high resolution png instead as eps.