# Making Mathematica graphics exported as PDF "usable" performance wise

Tags: export, pdf-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exporting graphics to PDF - huge file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file)
>   [Saner alternative to ContourPlot fill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill)
>   [How can all those tiny polygons generated by RegionPlot be joined into a single FilledCurve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/644/5)

When exporting a 3D plot to PDF my viewer takes quite long to render the PDF, which especially makes for a very bad scrolling experience. I've also tried exporting as EPS, but that seems to be much worse, especially when trying to load the generated files in Illustrator (a simple graph took a minute to load and Illustrator needed 5Gb of memory for it...).

I don't really want to include the graphics as rasterized images in my thesis :(

Comment: @R.M: Thanks, but the graphics I'm exporting is really simple, [nothing fancy at all](http://cl.ly/image/2h0L2W2D3t3R). It is just the exported PDF that is not so nice.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Yeah that'd be possible, but then I'd still be including rasterized images (convert doesn't really convert them to vector graphics, it just embeds the JPEGs in a PDF).

Comment: If your plot is a 3D plot, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file). For other types of plots, see also: [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps), [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill) and [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/644/5)

Comment: @x3ro, If your graph is really simple, try `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"`. It may not affect the graph appearance appreciably.

Comment: No worries. See the first link in F'x's comment. This is the exact same problem as that one