# Colouring in a FilledCurve, self-intersections and all

Tags: graphics, filling

I have a (vaguely) complex curve with some self-intersections, and I would like to add a filling to the interior. However, the recommended method (of turning `Line`s into [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html)s), i.e. by doing something like

```
ParametricPlot[
  {Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t], Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t]}
  , {t, 0, 2 π}
  , Frame -> True
  ] /. {Line[pts_] :> {FilledCurve[{Line[pts]}]}}
```

is unsatisfactory, since, as the documentation puts it,

> Filled curves can be non-convex and intersect themselves. Self-intersecting curves are filled according to an even-odd rule that alternates between filling and not at each crossing.

This puts a big hole in the middle of my figure that I would also like to fill:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I control the filling in that hole?

Comment: `ParametricPlot[
 r {Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t], Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 
  1}, Frame -> True]`

Comment: @Bob That's nowhere near sufficient - try e.g. changing the weight between the two components.

Comment: Related: [(9406)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9406/121), [(11517)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11517/121)

Comment: That Mathematica does not have an option to disable this behavior is a pretty significant limitation compared to, say, [SVG](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-svg-fill-rule-property/).

Answer (score 4):

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t], Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π} , 
        Frame -> True ] /. {Line[pts_] :> {FilledCurve[Line@pts]}};

bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[pp[[1]], Frame->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[pp[[1]], Frame->True, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Directive[Thick, Blue], {2} -> Yellow}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, use `bdg` in `RegionPlot` (thanks: @Mr.Wizard):

```
 RegionPlot @ bdg
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note:** In version 11, `bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @@ pp` also works.

Comment: In v10.1 I need `bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @@ pp[[1]];` -- if that doesn't break code in other versions you might make that change.

Comment: That's some pretty interesting tooling.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, i made the change,

Comment: Thanks.  Depending on the OP's needs `RegionPlot[bdg]` may be sufficient and significantly cleaner.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you again. Added the `RegionPlot` alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Now we can use `WindingPolygon` since v12.

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t], Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t]}, {t, 
    0, 2 π}, Frame -> True];
plot /. Line[pts_] :> 
   WindingPolygon[pts, "NonzeroRule"] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

[image]

Or

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
plot = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t] + 2  Cos[2  t], 
   Sin[t] - 2  Sin[2  t]}, {t, 0, 2  π}, Frame -> True];
m = 
 ToElementMesh@
  DiscretizeGraphics[plot]@"MakeRepresentation"@"ElementMesh"
m // MeshRegion // BoundaryMesh
```

Comment: `plot = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t], Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t]}, {t, 
   0, 2 π}, Frame -> True]; 
NDSolve\`FEM\`ToElementMesh[
   DiscretizeGraphics[plot]["MakeRepresentation"["ElementMesh"]]] // 
  MeshRegion // BoundaryMesh`

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
xss = Table[{Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t] + 2, Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 
    2 \[Pi], 1/100}];
regionPlot[xss_] := ListLinePlot[
  xss, 
  Filling -> {Axis}, 
  FillingStyle -> LightBlue, 
  AspectRatio -> 1,
   Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False,
   PlotStyle -> Transparent]
regionPlot@xss
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Some notes: my region need not be centered at the origin, and I would like to explicitly avoid double-filling.