# There are mesh grids when Export RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, export, mesh

When setting the `Opacity` option, there are mesh grids on the background of the pdf file. `Opacity` option should be saved because some shapes may be overlay.

**Version:12.2, Windows 10**

```
ff = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.6]]]
Export["ff.pdf", ff]
```

`Mesh->none` option not work. Is there any way to remove the mesh grids when exporting the image?

[image]

Comment: Add the setting `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}` to `RegionPlot[]` and report back.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Can you mention your OS and version number of *Mathematica* for reference?

Comment: I add the version number and OS: Version 12.2, Windows 10.

Comment: An old but highly related question: [(644)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/644/17).

Answer (score 4):

I get the same meshed result as @zongxian with and without @J.M.'s recommendation. I am using:

```
$Version
(* "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

A possible workaround is to use [`Region`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) with the appropriate specification like so:

```
ff = Region[
  Style[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}], Gray,
    Opacity[0.6]], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
Export["ff.pdf", ff]
```

The PDF is close to what is desired as shown below:

[image: PDF output]