# Meshgrid Visible in RegionPlot when Saving Figure as PDF

Tags: plotting, mesh, pdf-format, save, eps-format

I have a region and a contour plot. My goal is to superimpose them to compare them. So, I used the `Opacity[]` on the region plot function but when I save the figure in *.pdf* or *.eps* format, the result is not how I expect, as you can see below. The meshgrid somehow is also visible!

[image]

In Mathematica notebook's output I do not see this meshgrid, but it is visible only when I save the figure in as *.pdf* or *.eps* formats. I have tried using the function `Mesh->None`, it does not work. I must use the `Opacity[]` function because I am trying to superimpose two figures. Is there any way to not show the meshgrid?

I have read similar questions here about meshgrid showing up in region plots but none of them talk about superimposing two figures. So, I don't think it should be counted as a duplicate. One of them suggested to change the meshgrid colour to the same as the color that that region has after the opacity applied but that wouldn't work if I am superimposing figures.

**My code:**

Here I define the functions that are plotted in the figures.

```
u[\[Alpha]_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Kappa]_] := \[Alpha] - \[Kappa] Cos[\
\[CapitalPhi]]
q[\[Alpha]_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Kappa]_] := 
 2 \[Alpha]^3 + 18 \[Alpha] (\[Kappa] Sin[\[CapitalPhi]])^2 - 
  27 \[Kappa]^2 u[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]]
p[\[Alpha]_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Kappa]_] := \[Alpha]^2 - 
  3 (\[Kappa] Sin[\[CapitalPhi]])^2
A[\[Alpha]_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Kappa]_] := ((2 \[Alpha])/3 + 
   1/3 ((-q[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]] + Sqrt[
      q[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]]^2 - 
       4 p[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]]^3])/2)^(1/3) + 
   p[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]]/
    3 ((-q[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]] + Sqrt[
      q[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]]^2 - 
       4 p[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], \[Kappa]]^3])/2)^(-(1/3)))^(1/2)
```

This is where I use RegionPlot and ContourPlot commands.

```
contour = 
  ContourPlot[{A[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], 2]}, {\[CapitalPhi], 0, 
    2 Pi}, {\[Alpha], -10, 10}];
```

This is where I use RegionPlot and ContourPlot commands.

```
region = RegionPlot[{q[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], 2]^2 - 
      4 p[\[Alpha], \[CapitalPhi], 2]^3 > 0}, {\[CapitalPhi], 0, 
    2 Pi}, {\[Alpha], -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 5, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Green, Opacity[0.5]}}];
```

Finally superimposing the figures.

```
Show[contour, region]
```

**Update:**

The linked question *There are mesh grids when Export RegionPlot* solves my question. However, they plot points are not enough and the rgion is not exactly how I expect it to be.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There are mesh grids when Export RegionPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239668/there-are-mesh-grids-when-export-regionplot) or [Problem with exporting RegionPlot as PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257039/problem-with-exporting-regionplot-as-pdf)

Comment: @cvgmt I added my code. I simplified it so that output is not exactly the same as the figure I posted.

Comment: @Domen Thank you. That does solves the issue of meshgrid showing up. However, it looks like there are not enough plot points when I plot the figure (shown above) using this method and the figure gets cut out. Is there a way to increase the plot points? It does not let me use ```PlotPoints -> 50``` inside the function ```Region[]``` and ```ImplicitRegion[]```

Comment: Perhaps you can write a new question to address this emergent problem?